# UPDATE FROM with a large table is slow and uses Seq Scans

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-performance, temporary-tables, postgresql-14

I have a large table (ultimately maybe a billion rows but currently ~26 million) for which I want to set a flag on the highest PK for a given grouping, in a one-off batch.

I chose to create a temporary table that stores the PKs that should be set `current=true`, the rest should be set `current=false`. I made a temporary table rather than a materialized view, but I think it would make no real difference.

The process of discovering the maximum ID for each is not too painful:

```sql
CREATE TABLE assertion (
    pk integer NOT NULL,
    a bigint NOT NULL,
    b bigint NOT NULL,
    c bigint NOT NULL,
    d integer NOT NULL,
    current boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX assertion_current_idx ON assertion USING btree (current) WHERE (current = true);
CREATE INDEX assertion_current_idx1 ON assertion USING btree (current);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX assertion_a_b_c_d_idx ON assertion USING btree (a, b, c, d) WHERE (current = true);

SELECT COUNT(pk) FROM assertion;

-- 26916858
-- Time: 2912.403 ms (00:02.912)

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE assertion_current AS
    (SELECT MAX(pk) as pk, a, b, c, d
      FROM assertion
      GROUP BY a, b, c, d);

-- Time: 72218.755 ms (01:12.219)

ANALYZE assertion_current;

CREATE INDEX ON assertion_current(pk);

-- Time: 22107.698 ms (00:22.108)

SELECT COUNT(pk) FROM assertion_current;

-- 26455092
-- Time: 15650.078 ms (00:15.650)
```

Per the count of `assertion_current`, we need to set the 'current' flag true for 98% of rows.

The tricky thing is how to update the `assertion` table in reasonable time based on the current values. There is a unique constraint on `a, b, c, d, current` which must be maintained, therefore the update to the `current` column needs to be atomic to avoid breaking the constraint.

I have a few options:

### Option 1

Update only those `current` values that change. This has the benefit of updating the smallest number of rows necessary based on an indexed field:

```sql
BEGIN;
UPDATE assertion
   SET current = false
   WHERE assertion.current = true AND PK NOT IN (SELECT pk FROM assertion_current);
UPDATE assertion
   SET current = true
   WHERE assertion.current = false AND PK IN (SELECT pk FROM assertion_current);
COMMIT;
```

But both queries involve sequence scans on `assertion_current` which (I think) would have to be multiplied by a large number of rows.

```
Update on assertion  (cost=0.12..431141.55 rows=0 width=0)
   ->  Index Scan using assertion_current_idx on assertion  (cost=0.12..431141.55 rows=1 width=7)
         Index Cond: (current = true)
         Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..787318.40 rows=29982560 width=4)
                 ->  Seq Scan on assertion_current  (cost=0.00..520285.60 rows=29982560 width=4)
```

and

```
 Update on assertion  (cost=595242.56..596693.92 rows=0 width=0)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=595242.56..596693.92 rows=17974196 width=13)
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=595242.00..595244.00 rows=200 width=10)
               Group Key: assertion_current.pk
               ->  Seq Scan on assertion_current  (cost=0.00..520285.60 rows=29982560 width=10)
         ->  Index Scan using assertion_pkey on assertion  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=10)
               Index Cond: (pk = assertion_current.pk)
               Filter: (NOT current)
```

This means that one of these queries (many current true or many current false) always takes a very long time.

### Option 2

Single pass but has to touch every row unnecessarily.

```
UPDATE assertion
   SET current =
     (CASE WHEN assertion.pk IN (select PK from assertion_current)
     THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END)
```

but this results in a sequence scan on assertion_current again

```
 Update on assertion  (cost=0.00..15498697380303.70 rows=0 width=0)
   ->  Seq Scan on assertion  (cost=0.00..15498697380303.70 rows=35948392 width=7)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..787318.40 rows=29982560 width=4)
                 ->  Seq Scan on assertion_current  (cost=0.00..520285.60 rows=29982560 width=4)
```

### Option 3

Like option 1, but use `WHERE` in the update:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE assertion SET current = false WHERE current = true;
UPDATE assertion SET current = true FROM assertion_current
  WHERE assertion.pk = assertion_current.pk;
COMMIT;
```

but the second query involves two seq scans:

```
 Update on assertion  (cost=1654256.82..2721576.65 rows=0 width=0)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=1654256.82..2721576.65 rows=29982560 width=13)
         Hash Cond: (assertion_current.pk = assertion.pk)
         ->  Seq Scan on assertion_current  (cost=0.00..520285.60 rows=29982560 width=10)
         ->  Hash  (cost=1029371.92..1029371.92 rows=35948392 width=10)
               ->  Seq Scan on assertion  (cost=0.00..1029371.92 rows=35948392 width=10)
```

### Option 4

Thanks @jjanes, this took > 6 hours, so I cancelled it.

```
UPDATE assertion
   SET current = not current
   WHERE current <>
     (CASE WHEN assertion.pk IN (select PK from assertion_current)
     THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END)
```

produces

```
 Update on assertion  (cost=0.00..11832617068493.14 rows=0 width=0)
   ->  Seq Scan on assertion  (cost=0.00..11832617068493.14 rows=27307890 width=7)
         Filter: (current <> CASE WHEN (SubPlan 1) THEN true ELSE false END)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..787318.40 rows=29982560 width=4)
                 ->  Seq Scan on assertion_current  (cost=0.00..520285.60 rows=29982560 width=4)
```

### Option 5

Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. This takes 24 minutes on my machine.

```
UPDATE assertion tg SET current = EXISTS (SELECT pk FROM assertion_current cr WHERE cr.pk = tg.pk);
```

gives

```
 Update on assertion tg  (cost=0.00..233024784.94 rows=0 width=0)
   ->  Seq Scan on assertion tg  (cost=0.00..233024784.94 rows=27445116 width=7)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Index Only Scan using assertion_current_pk_idx on assertion_current cr  (cost=0.44..8.46 rows=1 width=0)
                 Index Cond: (pk = tg.pk)
```

Is there a better way to achieve this in a timely fashion?

Comment: Thanks, that was a copy-paste error (I anonymised irrelevant fields to make it easier to read).

Comment: I think anonymised names are actually much _harder_ to read ;)

Comment: Have you tried an EXISTS condition? https://pastebin.com/eKW8FeEs

Comment: Thanks very much, I've added that option with the query plan, and I'm trying it now.

Comment: I get an index scan on `assertion_current` https://explain.depesz.com/s/hqLy

Comment: I'm so sorry, you're right. I'd rebuilt the table without adding the index. I'm timing it again now!

Comment: `the 'current' flag is true for 98% of rows`. So there are only ~ 1.02 rows per group? Is this how it's going to be?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, it's going to be 98% at the point where I run this query (after an initial bulk data load). After that point in time, the characteristics may change, but the volume of data load will be lower.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that query completed in reasonable time, thank you. Do you want to provide it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... we need to set the 'current' flag true for 98% of rows

So `NOT current` will be the rare case. Seems like you have been trying to do things back to front so far.

Your **current indexes are actively unhelpful** for the given data distribution:

```
CREATE INDEX assertion_current_idx ON assertion USING btree (current) WHERE (current = true);  
CREATE INDEX assertion_current_idx1 ON assertion USING btree (current);  
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX assertion_a_b_c_d_idx ON assertion USING btree (a, b, c, d) WHERE (current = true);
```

We need to keep the `UNIQUE` index to enforce your requirements, and it's useful, too:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX assertion_a_b_c_d_idx ON assertion (a, b, c, d) WHERE current;
```

But simplify `(current = true)` to just `current`. No point in executing a redundant expression, just use the `boolean` value.

<strike>`assertion_current_idx`</strike> is absolutely pointless and will never be used. But it still has to be kept up to date. Drop it.

<strike>`assertion_current_idx1`</strike> is almost as pointless. At least it would make sense for queries looking for `current = false`. But it's **much cheaper** to have this partial index instead - which also supports my suggested 2nd query below:

```
CREATE INDEX assertion_not_current_idx ON assertion (a, b, c, d, pk) WHERE NOT current;
```

Create this index ***after*** the "initial query" below.

Note that I skip the temporary table completely in favor of a CTE. Less overhead.

#### Initial query

You disclosed in a later comment that ***"all rows are set `current = false`"*** initially. We can use a **much simpler and faster query** to init. Just update the one row per group where there is no other with a bigger PK. No unique violations possible, no updates to "not current":

```
UPDATE assertion a
SET    current = true
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM assertion x
   WHERE (x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d)
       = (a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d)
   AND   x.pk > a.pk
   );
```

#### General query

Assuming there can be *no* current row per group.

```
WITH new_current AS (  -- only these groups require updates
   SELECT *
   FROM  (
      -- get row with greatest non-current pk per group
      SELECT a, b, c, d, MAX(pk) AS new_pk
          , (SELECT a2.pk  -- get current row of the same group
             FROM   assertion a2
             WHERE (a2.a, a2.b, a2.c, a2.d)
                 = (a1.a, a1.b, a1.c, a1.d)
             AND    a2.current
            ) AS old_pk
      FROM   assertion a1
      WHERE  NOT current
      GROUP  BY a, b, c, d
      ) a1
   WHERE (old_pk < new_pk   -- only if old pk is lower (!)
       OR old_pk IS NULL)   -- or does not exist
   )
, up1(dummy) AS (  -- update current to false FIRST
   UPDATE assertion a
   SET    current = false
   FROM   new_current n
   WHERE  (a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d, a.pk)
        = (n.a, n.b, n.c, n.d, n.old_pk)  -- only matches existing old pk
   RETURNING true
   )
UPDATE assertion a  -- then update the new current row
SET    current = true
FROM   new_current n
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT FROM up1 LIMIT 1) AS force_update_order ON true  -- !!!
WHERE  (a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d, a.pk)
     = (n.a, n.b, n.c, n.d, n.new_pk);
```

Should ***dwarf*** anything else you tried so far.

Subquery `a1` gets the row with greatest non-current `pk` per group with a simple `max()` aggregation. That's the optimum while there are *few* candidate rows (`NOT current`) per group. Else, optimize this step further with an emulated index skip scan:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [Best performance to get distinct values for a given key from a big table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/313054/best-performance-to-get-distinct-values-for-a-given-key-from-a-big-table/313060#313060)

The tricky part is to **keep the `UNIQUE` constraint happy**. It does not allow two current rows per group at any given time. There is no order of execution among CTEs of the same query - as long as one does not reference the other. I put in such a dummy reference to **force the order of updates**.

When there was no current row, yet, the CTE `up1` returns no row. So we use `LEFT JOIN`. And `LIMIT 1` to never duplicate rows.

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort in this answer! The indexes you suggest dropping are there for query time not for index time, so I included them to illustrate how the table will be used. I was hoping to avoid dropping indexes during data ingestion (might make schema migrations potentially more fragile) but I will certainly try your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry are you missing a definition of `a2` in that query?

Comment: @Joe Yes, alias `a2` fixed now.

Comment: This is not working as expected: when all rows are set `current = false` (the initial state of the table), this query terminates immediately, but makes no updates. 

`new_current` returns 0 rows when I think we would expect it to return all rows that should be set true. `a1` _does_ correctly return many rows (the 98%). But `WHERE a2.current` is false for all rows in this scenario, so the JOIN is empty. 

I might have misunderstood the query, but it appears that it's not designed to be run on a table with no `current=true`?

Comment: @Joe: I updated accordingly. (I also had an error: `old_pk < new_pk` warrants updates, not `>`.) Please clarify the initial state in your question to match.

Comment: Thank you for all your effort in this answer. The initial update runs approximately at the same speed as Option 5 (27 minutes) and when I zero and rebuild the last 10% the second query takes 6 seconds which extrapolates to a significant 27x speedup.

May I use code in an MIT-licensed project? Do you require attribution, if so, how?

Comment: @Joe: MIT licence is fine with me. Attribution to my name please.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should try to avoid every seq scan.  But you do not want a seq scan which will be executed a large number of times (like in a un-hashed subplan, or in the 2nd child of a nested loop).

In your first plan, it does have a seq scan in an unhashed subplan, but it claims this will only be executed once, so it would not be too bad if that is accurate.  But that does seem to contradict your description of "the 'current' flag is true for 98% of rows", so maybe the stats are just grossly wrong.

You could increase our work_mem until the subplan switches to a hashed subplan, or you could rewrite your query from NOT IN to NOT EXISTS.

In the case of option 2, you could just add a WHERE to eliminate the inoperative updates:

```
UPDATE assertion
   SET current = not current
   WHERE current <>  
     (CASE WHEN assertion.pk IN (select PK from assertion_current)
     THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END)
```

But again using EXISTS rather IN is likely to be better.

Comment: Thanks very much, that current check is inspired! I've added it, and the query plan, to my question. But I'm trying out the EXISTS first.