# Check int4range includes number using B-tree index

Tags: postgresql, index, btree, range-types, integer

I have a table with two important columns: `value` and `m_range`, where `value`:

```
CREATE TABLE m_filter (                                                  
    value     BIGINT NOT NULL,
    m_range   int4range NOT NULL,
    EXCLUDE   USING GIST (m_range WITH &&, value WITH =)
);
```

The usage scenario is following:

1. It's not frequently updated, but it can contain a quite large amount of data.
2. It's queries very frequently by searching for `value`s, which are in `m_range`.

So I'm supposing to use `BTree` index for `m_range` column instead of `Gist` for better query performance:

```
CREATE INDEX i_m_filter_range ON m_filter USING BTREE (m_range);
```

But according to docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html BTree indexes supports only these operators:
`<   <=   =   >=   >`.

Is it possible to select all `value`s where `int4range` columnt contains some `integer` using BTree? Like I can do with ranges using `@>` and `<@` operators.

---

Update:

In this table `m_range` values could be int values from 0 to 9999, each `value` has about 500 non-overlaping `m_range` records average, and there are about 1_000 `value`s, so it's about 500_000 `m_range` values.

PostgreSQL version is 13.5

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't it the `@>` (containment) operator you are looking for? That is supported by the GiST index.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe no, I'm looking for operator which is supported by btree index

Comment: No, btree can't support that efficiently in the general case.  What is the problem with using the constraint index?  What does `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` show (please turn track_io_timing on if it is not already).  How much faster does it need to be?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Can some of the values be inside the range and some outside of the range? It would be good if you could provide a representative sample of your data at dbfiddle.uk along with your PostgreSQL version number. How many records do you have in total - approximately?

Comment: What is the distribution of values? How many ranges are there per value? Or values per range?

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні Hi, thanks, I added more details to my question. I'm not sure if I can upload 500k rows in https://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: I would suggest you do NOT try to upload 500k rows in dbfiddle.uk. But as previous commenters asked, please explain why the performance of the current queries in not good enough (and add the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output, when run with your 500k data).

Comment: Is there also a table holding the 1000 distinct `value`s?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have **relatively few distinct values**, there is an **efficient solution with a B-tree index**. Probably faster than a query based on the GiST index for more than a few result rows. The GiST solution will be faster for few result rows, approaching the task from the opposite direction.

#### Setup

Let's store separate integer columns for lower and upper bound instead of `int4range`. Also only needs 8 bytes of storage instead of 14 (+ 4 bytes of alignment padding) for `int4range`.

```
CREATE TABLE m_filter (
  value bigint NOT NULL
, m_lo  int4 NOT NULL  -- incl. lower bound
, m_hi  int4 NOT NULL  -- excl. upper bound
, EXCLUDE USING gist (int4range(m_lo, m_hi) WITH &&, value WITH =)
);
```

Downside 1: the exclusion constraint is based on an expression and a bit slower.

Downside 2: the exclusion constraint creates a GiST index implicitly. So a query with the [range containment operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) would work out of the box, no additional index needed.

For the B-tree solution, create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX m_filter_value_lo_hi_idx ON m_filter (value, m_lo DESC, m_hi);
```

We *could* also make it work with `int4range`. Just more overhead and slower results.

#### Query 1 - with values table

Assuming there is also a table `dist_values` with one row per distinct `value` - something that's commonly present in one form or another:

```
CREATE TABLE dist_values (
  value bigint PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then it's ***fast***:

```
SELECT v.value
FROM   dist_values v
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM m_filter m
   WHERE  m.value = v.value
   AND    m.m_lo <= 55
   AND    m.m_hi >  55
   );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=340208a5d082940ad45fafe154c2e6e3)*

1 index(-only) lookup per `value`. Makes always only 1000 of them in your case.

#### Query 2 - without values table

If there is no table `dist_values`, we can still make it pop with an emulated index-skip scan:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (   -- parentheses required
   SELECT value, true AS hit
   FROM   m_filter v
   WHERE  EXISTS ( -- ①
      SELECT FROM m_filter m
      WHERE  m.value = v.value
      AND    m.m_lo <= 55 -- $my_int
      AND    m.m_hi >  55 -- $my_int
      )
   ORDER  BY 1
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT v.*
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT v.value
           , EXISTS ( -- ②
               SELECT FROM m_filter m
               WHERE  m.value = v.value
               AND    m.m_lo <= 55 -- $my_int
               AND    m.m_hi >  55 -- $my_int
               ) AS hit
      FROM   m_filter v
      WHERE  v.value > c.value  -- lateral reference
      ORDER  BY 1
      LIMIT  1
      ) v
   )
SELECT value
FROM   cte
WHERE  hit;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=340208a5d082940ad45fafe154c2e6e3)*

Still fast, if not as fast.

① We can skip ahead in the initial term.
② But we need to keep all values in the recursive term, so not to terminate recursion.

See:

- [Best performance to get distinct values for a given key from a big table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/313054/best-performance-to-get-distinct-values-for-a-given-key-from-a-big-table/313060#313060)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)