# Getting first messages only for every day in a specific date range

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Table `messages`:

| conv_id | user_id | content | sent_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 1st_msg | 01-01-1990 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 002 | 2nd_msg | 02-01-1990 00:00:00 |

How do we select the first message and the first reply sent in a conversation (`conv_id`) every day?

Notes:

1. There can be many users.
2. A single user can send multiple messages.
3. This is a dataset of people, and only two people are chatting with each other.
4. Throughout the day, multiple messages get exchanged.
5. First message can be defined by the minimum sent time within day 1 of the first user.
6. First reply can be defined as the minimum sent time within day 1 of the second user.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: it is a general query. Either of the answer is fine for me.

Comment: "First few messages" or "first message"? Big difference. How is "first" defined exactly? By `sent_time`? Why `id = 1` twice? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes 'sent_time' can be used to define first message. Now that i think about it. id column has no use at all. Can ignore. i have deleted that column

Comment: I assume both rows in your example should have the same `conv_id` to be part of the same conversation?

Comment: Yes. But there are thousands of users. Not just two. But only two can be part of 1 conversation.

Comment: Your version of Postgres and the actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) showing data types and constraints would be instrumental.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137303/discussion-between-n3a5p7s9t1e3r-and-erwin-brandstetter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a truly simple solution with `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('day', sent_time), conv_id, user_id)
       *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY date_trunc('day', sent_time), conv_id, user_id, sent_time;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cbfe8cdb17bcb1da0af591afb625040e)*

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

An emulated index-skip may be faster. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [Best performance to get distinct values for a given key from a big table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/313054/best-performance-to-get-distinct-values-for-a-given-key-from-a-big-table/313060#313060)

In case of `timestamptz`, "days" are defined by the timezone setting of your current session, unless defined explicitly. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Comment: Thank you it works like a charm. Do you mind telling how do we count the number that this query returns??

Comment: @33a5G7s9t1e3L: I don't know what "count the number" means. Please start a new *question* if you have a new question.