# counting minimum sent_time for everyday

Tags: postgresql, count, greatest-n-per-group

Postgres 14

db fiddle updated - [Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a99ba2fd6f0dfe8e304adb4a3afe2178)

EDIT:
It seems like I need 1 more row:
CREATED AT - specifies when conversation was created.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('day', sent_time), conv_id, user_id)
       *
FROM   messages
ORDER  BY date_trunc('day', sent_time), conv_id, user_id, sent_time;
```

Here, I want to count every first message sent. Can we use minimum of sent_time of every single date? I want the Count.

Returns:

| conv_id | user_id | content | sent_time | created_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | `1` | `1st_msg` | `01-01-2021 00:01` | `01-01-2021 00:01` |
| 1 | 1 | 4th_msg | 01-01-2021 00:01 | 01-01-2021 00:01 |
| 1 | 2 | 2nd_msg | 01-01-2021 00:01 | 01-01-2021 00:01 |
| 1 | 2 | 3rd_msg | 01-01-2021 00:01 | 01-01-2021 00:01 |
| `2` | `1` | `1st_msg` | `02-01-2021 00:02` | `01-01-2021 00:01` |
| 2 | 1 | 4th_msg | 02-01-2021 00:02 | 01-01-2021 00:01 |
| 2 | 2 | 2nd_msg | 02-01-2021 00:02 | 01-01-2021 00:01 |
| 2 | 2 | 3rd_msg | 02-01-2021 00:02 | 01-01-2021 00:01 |
| `3` | `2` | `2nd_msg` | `03-01-2021 00:03` | `01-01-2021 00:01` |
| 3 | 2 | 4th_msg | 03-01-2021 00:03 | 01-01-2021 00:01 |

**Expected Answer:**

1. First message on 1st Day of Jan was - 1st msg - COUNT 1
2. First message on 2nd Day of Jan was - 1st msg - COUNT 2
   .
   .
   .
   n - counts

- What is `n` or `number of first messages`?

Comment: Hi - and welcome to dba.se! You appear to want to count new conversations? `Can we use minimum of sent_time of every single date? I want the Count.`. No, you can't! The dates are pretty arbitrary per conversation - you could have 5 conversations start on the same day - each with different 1st message times. Also, you could have a long conversation which started on day x and went over into x+1 at 10s after midnight Unless I've misunderstood, is [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d445ee9afbba7c3807596a712046e5dd) what you want? If so, I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні Thanks for the reply. What if we add the created_at column. Is it then possible to count the first messages? Please see the edited question

Comment: So  do you want 3 records in the answer?  Please construct a table with your desired result and put it into the question. Notify me when done.

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні I have updated my requirements more clearly.  This below code will only count the number of unique conversations. What I am looking for is to figure out the count of first messages sent in each conversation.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT(conv_id)) AS msg_count
FROM 
  messages;
```

Answer (score 1):

It *sounds* like you are looking for the number of conversations started each day:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', sent_time) AS the_day, count(*) AS conversations_started
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (conv_id)  sent_time
   FROM   messages
   ORDER  BY conv_id, sent_time
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;  -- optional
```

| the_day | conversations_started |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c81510e0ff346e568b0b6726707ab763)*

Again, performance optimization possible for *many* rows per conversation. And  "the day" is not well defined while data type (and time zone for `timestamptz`) are not well defined. Like in your previous question:

- [Getting first messages only for every day in a specific date range](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/313707/getting-first-messages-only-for-every-day-in-a-specific-date-range/313718#313718)