# How to constrain row values in one table to match row values in another table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, unique-constraint

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE operation
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;
);

CREATE TABLE listing
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  operation_id BIGINT REFERENCES operation (id)
);

CREATE TABLE listing_card
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  listing_id BIGINT REFERENCES listing (id),
  listing_operation_id BIGINT REFERENCES operation (id),
  index SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (listing_operation_id, index)
);
```

- Multiple listings may reference the same operation.

How do I ensure that table `listing` contains a `(id, operation_id)` combination that matches `listing_card`'s `(listing_id, listing_operation_id)`?

I want something along the lines of `FOREIGN KEY (listing_id, listing_operation_id) REFERENCES listing (id, operation_id)` but I cannot do this because `(id, operation_id)` is not unique (multiple listings could reference the same operation).

Operations are referenced by different kinds of tables. The ultimate goal of the above schema is to ensure that `listing_card.index` is unique across any listing operations. A single operation may be referenced by 3 different listings, but their card indexes must be unique across each other (across the entire operation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want something along the lines of `FOREIGN KEY (listing_id, listing_operation_id) REFERENCES listing (id, operation_id)` but I
> cannot do this because `(id, operation_id)` is not unique (multiple
> listings could reference the same operation).

No, this is a misunderstanding. `listing.id` is the PK, so `(id, operation_id)` is guaranteed to be `UNIQUE`, and you can proceed as planned.

While being at it, make that `UNIQUE` constraint on `(operation_id, id)`, since `id` is already indexed via PK anyway. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Comment: Oops. Good point. Thank you for pointing this out. Once I added a `UNIQUE` constraint on `listing (id, operation_id)` I was able to add the corresponding `FOREIGN KEY` to `listing_card`.

Comment: And you only need the two-column FK. The other 2 FKs from listing_card can be removed.

Comment: If I were to drop `listing_card.listing_operation_id` as you suggested, I wouldn't be able to enforce the cross-table constraint `UNIQUE (listing_operation_id, index)`, right? So I don't think this column is redundant.

Comment: @Gili: I forgot about your last paragraph when adding the bit about dropping `listing_operation_id`. So you need the column. Removing my misguided addition again.