# Optimal way to get a total count of rows in a paged query in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, cte, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions, pagination

I need to improve the performance of a paged query for customer orders in a Type2 Postgres db (always insert a new record with a new ID, the newest ID is the current version of the record). Changing away from Type2 is not an option at this time. The query I have is two queries with the same CTE in both:

```
WITH customer_orders AS (
    select id, order_id, customer_id,
    "name", country, state, county, source_system, 
    is_deleted, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at,
    created_by, updated_by, deleted_by, 
    rank() over (partition by order_id order by id desc) as entity_rank 
    from orders WHERE customer_id = $1 and is_deleted= $2
  )
SELECT * FROM customer_orders where entity_rank = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $3 OFFSET $4;


WITH customer_orders AS (
    select id, order_id, customer_id,
    "name", country, state, county, source_system, 
    is_deleted, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at,
    created_by, updated_by, deleted_by, 
    rank() over (partition by order_id order by id desc) as entity_rank 
    from orders WHERE customer_id = $1 and is_deleted= $2
    )
SELECT count(id) FROM customer_orders where entity_rank = 1;
```

But I wonder if there's a better way to do this, can I select from the CTE twice, once for the paging (limit + offset) and once for the total number of records? I'll be running this as two separate queries from a Node process. It seems like it should be doable in one query but I can't get it.

Indexes: id (PK), order_id, customer_id, is_deleted (1 on each of those)

Comment: Knowing the table and index definitions would be helpful.

Comment: added the indexes, the select in the CTE is all the fields in the table

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: "*Indexes: id (PK), order_id, customer_id, is_deleted*" - Is this 1, 2, 3, or 4 indexes? Please try to be clearer on the details you provide. Please see mustaccio's advice.

Comment: What is a `Type2 Postgres db`? As opposed to `Type1`? Or `Type-whatever` - there are PostgreSQL databases (current supported versions [11 - 15](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)) - those are the only `Types` of PostgreSQL database that I know about - maybe you could expand on this?

Comment: @Vérace https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can reuse the same CTE multiple times, and that's typically faster than running multiple queries. (But you can only *return* from a query once.)

But you don't even have to for the use case. Just add a window function in the outer `SELECT`:

```
WITH customer_orders AS (
   SELECT id, order_id, customer_id
        , "name", country, state, county, source_system
        , is_deleted, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
        , created_by, updated_by, deleted_by
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY id DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS entity_rank
   FROM   orders
   WHERE  customer_id = $1
   AND    is_deleted = $2
   )
SELECT *, count(*) OVER () AS total_count
FROM   customer_orders
WHERE  entity_rank = 1
ORDER  BY id DESC
LIMIT  $3
OFFSET $4;
```

See:

- [Run a query with a LIMIT/OFFSET and also get the total number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28888696/939860)

You don't even *need* a CTE at all now. A plain subquery does the job. (But doesn't make much of a difference any more since Postgres 12.)

```
SELECT *, count(*) OVER () AS total_count
FROM  (
   SELECT id, order_id, customer_id
        , "name", country, state, county, source_system
        , is_deleted, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
        , created_by, updated_by, deleted_by
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY id DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS entity_rank
   FROM   orders
   WHERE  customer_id = $1
   AND    is_deleted = $2
   ) customer_orders
WHERE  entity_rank = 1
ORDER  BY id DESC
LIMIT  $3
OFFSET $4;
```

While being at it, I replaced `rank()` with the more appropriate (and faster) `row_number()`. I also added the custom frame definition `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` to help performance. (Obsolete, but harmless, in Postgres 16 or later.) See:

- [Efficient downsampling of a selected timeseries to equidistant samples](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320935/efficient-downsampling-of-a-selected-timeseries-to-equidistant-samples/320943#320943)

This multicolumn **index** can probably help performance (a lot):

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON orders (customer_id, is_deleted, order_id, id DESC);
```

More performance optimization may be possible, highly likely even. But that depends on undisclosed details of your setup. You'd have to provide [information for performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/3684) as requested in the comments.
Basics:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291099/939860)

Comment: Dang this is very helpful, will implement this when I'm back at the office

Comment: Huge improvement; used the 2nd one. A query that was taking ~25s down to ~200ms; thanks for the help

Comment: @jcollum: Nice. Pretty sure this can be much faster still. Test the index I added. Or provide information as instructed.

Comment: Usually, the best think is *not* to calculate the total result set count. Estimate with `EXPLAIN` or only calculate the count on explicit demand.