# Does a multicolumn unique index support my query?

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-13

Using PostgreSQL-13, I need advice about key index. I have a table named "employee" and I manage my DB using DBeaver Community Edition (latest).

```
Fieldname      Type
----------     ----
pid            bigint -  nextval('employee_pid_seq'::regclass) -- 
Primary Key
company_id     varchar(10)
employee_id    varchar(10)
employee_name  varchar(50)
```

I'm learning to fine-tune this simple table. `company_id` and `employee_id` is a unique index.

When running:

```
select * from employee order by company_id
```

... to enhance the performance, do I also need to have `company_id` as non-unique index?

Comment: *do I also need to have company_id as non-unique index?* No. The index prefix of `UNIQUE (company_id, employee_id)` will be used.

Comment: PS. `id` as VARCHAR is not good idea. Use numeric datatype (INT for example) instead.

Comment: Note that `identity` columns (`generated always as identity`)  are recommended for auto-generated primary key values. `company_id` should probably be a foreign key. Not sure why you have a `employee_id` (which sounds like another foreign key column) **and** an `employee_name`. If employee_id is a foreign key the name should be stored in the referenced table.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a unique index (or constraint, same effect) on `(company_id, employee_id)`, you typically don't need another index on just `(company_id)`.
The multicolumn index with leading `company_id` supports your `ORDER BY`. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)