# Create an index on a very large table to filter on date, or date + id

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance

I am creating a table where I will have a large volume of data and the search will always be based on a date, or a date + an ID. I want to create an index to support the queries, but I have no idea how to create this index for date.

My query:

```
create table if not exists example_table (
    id                  serial  primary key,
    original_created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    external_id         text not null,
    category            text NOT NULL,
    user_id             uuid not null,
    data                jsonb not null default '{}'::jsonb,

    constraint external_id_uq unique (external_id)
);
```

Example:
Most of the searches will be for the `original_created_at` or `original_created_at` + `user_id` field. I want to optimize performance for the search to only get values ​​from that date.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you have a problem with? Are you struggling with the `create index` syntax? Something else?

Comment: only with create index.

Comment: and what is the best way to create the index for these queries

Comment: Side note : if the table is planned to be really large, `bigserial` would be much better choice than `serial`.  Max int is not really big - just a bit greater than 2 billions , and you can reach it relatively quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You speak of "date", but `original_created_at` is type `timestamptz`. I assume you do not actually want *"values ​​from that date"*, but just for that timestamp.

A single multicolumn index can cover searches for either: `original_created_at` or for `original_created_at` + `user_id`. Just make sure to put `original_created_at` first:

```
CREATE INDEX ON example_table (original_created_at, user_id);
```

See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Also, I would rearrange table columns to save a couple of bytes per row and make your searches a tiny bit faster yet, with the two filter columns first:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example_table (
  original_created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
, user_id             uuid NOT NULL
, id                  serial  PRIMARY KEY  -- do you actually have use for this?
, external_id         text NOT NULL
, category            text NOT NULL
, data                jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb
, CONSTRAINT external_id_uq UNIQUE (external_id)
);
```

See:

- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)

Since `external_id_uq` is `UNIQUE NOT NULL` anyway, you may be able to drop the surrogate PK column `id`.

`bigint` is more efficient for `user_id` than `uuid`. Not least, it makes above index smaller. Only use the type `uuid` if you actually need it. See:

- [PostgreSQL using UUID vs Text as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33838373/939860)

If there are lots of rows for the same timestamp (or timestamp + id combo), and rows are physically sorted, a [BRIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPES-BRIN) may be an alternative due its small size.