# 2 B-tree indices OR 1 GiST index on tsrange -- which will perform better?

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, postgresql-9.2, gist-index

I have a table which is storing reservation data using the columns `starts_at` & `ends_at` Whenever I'm querying the table to find overlapping reservations, I have an option of using one of the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations
WHERE starts_at < '2014-01-03 00:00:00'
AND   ends_at   >='2014-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM reservations
WHERE tsrange(starts_at, ends_at) && ('2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-01-03 00:00:00')
```

I have regular B-Tree indices on the `starts_at` and `ends_at` columns, therefore the first query is always using them. However, unless I define a functional GiST index on the tsrange, the second query does a complete scan.

```
create index tsrange_idx on reservations using gist(tsrange(starts_at, ends_at));
```

My question is, as the table grows, which index is going to be faster? Probably the answer is obvious looking at the query execution plan, but I'm not well-versed with reading `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns To summarise both should work relatively well. It is hard to give a definitive answer without testing with real world data.

Comment: i am getting this error which creating index help is appreciated SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function tsrange(timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 52

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Timestamps with B-tree index

I suggest a **third option**: as long as your table holds two `timestamp` columns (which seem to be defined `NOT NULL`) I would use a single [multicolumn B-tree index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) with **opposed** sort order (if no other considerations apply):

```
CREATE INDEX reservations_range_idx ON reservations (starts_at, ends_at DESC);
```

More in these related answer:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns)
- [PostgreSQL index not used for query on range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14407839/939860)

As for the query, have a look at the [SQL-standard operator **`OVERLAPS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE):

```
SELECT * FROM reservations
WHERE (starts_at, ends_at) OVERLAPS ('2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-01-03 00:00:00');
```

More in this related question on SO:

- [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15305292/939860)

Should be faster than two B-tree indices. Less disk space and cheaper to maintain. The burden on write operations is small.

#### Range type with GiST index

With big tables, a [GiST index on a range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-GIST) is most probably faster, because it scales better. Storage on disk is considerably bigger and index maintenance a bit more expensive, though.

If you go that route, it would be more efficient to store your timestamps as range ([`tsrange` or `tstzrange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html)) to begin with. A plain GiST index without the functional aspect is a bit faster.

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (
  reservation_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, span tsrange
, ...
);
 
CREATE INDEX reservation_span_gist_idx on reservations USING GiST (span);
```

With the [`&&` "overlap" operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) you already displayed in the question:

```
SELECT *
FROM   reservation 
WHERE  span && ('2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-01-03 00:00:00');
```

You might be interested in an **exclusion constraint** to rule out overlaps by design, which implements a GiST index like the one above automatically. There is a [code example in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT). This related answer on SO has more details:

- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19505869/939860)