# Writing a view that caches to another table

Tags: postgresql, insert, aggregate, plpgsql

I have a table `market_trades` with columns `timestamp`, `market_id`, and `amount`:

```
api_production=# \d market_trades;
                                       Table "public.market_trades"
     Column     |            Type             |                         Modifiers                          
----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                     | not null default nextval('market_trades_id_seq'::regclass)
 market_id      | integer                     | not null
 timestamp      | timestamp without time zone | not null
 amount         | numeric(16,8)               | not null
```

And I just created a table `market_trades_sum_cache`:

```
api_production=# \d market_trades_sum_cache;
                                       Table "public.market_trades_sum_cache"
     Column     |            Type             |                         Modifiers                          
----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                     | not null default nextval('market_trades_sum_cache_id_seq'::regclass)
 market_id      | integer                     | not null
 start_time     | timestamp without time zone | not null
 end_time       | timestamp without time zone | not null
 sum            | numeric(16,8)               | not null
```

I want to write a view (or some other type of reusable function) called `trade_volume` that takes a `market_id`, `start_time`, and `end_time` as parameters and does the following:

1. If there is a row in `market_trades_sum_cache` with the given `market_id`, `start_time`, and `end_time`, return the corresponding `sum`.
2. Otherwise, add up the `amount`s of all rows in `market_trades` with the given `market_id` and whose `timestamp` is between `start_time` and `end_time`, store that sum as a new row in `market_trades_sum_cache`, and return the sum.

Is this possible in PostgreSQL 9.3?

**BONUS:** Use PostgreSQL's timestamp range types (`tsrange` in PostgreSQL 9.2+) instead of `start_time` and `end_time` in `market_trades_sum_cache`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trade_volume (_market_id  int
                                       , _start_time timestamp
                                       , _end_time   timestamp)
  RETURNS SETOF numeric(16,8) AS
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
SELECT sum                          -- dubious identifier
FROM   market_trades_sum_cache
WHERE  market_id  = _market_id
AND    start_time = _start_time
AND    end_time   = _end_time;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
   RETURN QUERY
   INSERT INTO market_trades_sum_cache(market_id, start_time, end_time, sum)
   SELECT market_id
        , _start_time
        , _end_time
        , sum(amount)
   FROM   market_trades
   WHERE  market_id = _market_id
   AND    timestamp BETWEEN _start_time AND _end_time
   GROUP  BY 1
   RETURNING sum;
END IF;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

#### A couple of warnings

- It's a bad idea to use names of basic functions (`sum`) or data types (`timestamp`) as column names.
- `BETWEEN` includes lower and upper bound. Often, you would rather include the lower, but *exclude* the upper bound.
- There is a tiny chance for a **race condition** in the above function. To be prepared for heavy concurrent load, consider this related answer:

  - [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

#### Alternative with `tsrange`

```
...
AND    ts_range = tsrange(_start_time, _end_time, '[]')
...
   INSERT INTO market_trades_sum_cache(market_id, ts_range, sum)
   SELECT market_id
        , tsrange(_start_time, _end_time, '[]')  -- incl. bounds
        , sum(amount)
   FROM   market_trades
   WHERE  market_id = _market_id
   AND    timestamp BETWEEN _start_time AND _end_time
   GROUP  BY 1
   RETURNING sum;
...
```

I would consider a multicolumn **GIN or GiST index** for the range type. Though, if you *only* check for equality, a btree index would do the job, too. But the latter isn't much use for anything else. [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING)

To include market_id in the index (like I'd suggest), you also need the additional module [btree_gin](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gin.html) or [btree_gist](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gist.html). Then create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX sum_mult_idx ON market_trades_sum_cache USING GIN (market_id, ts_range, sum);
```

The last column `sum` is optional and only makes sense if you get **index-only scans** out of it. Else don't include it in the index.

**Or**, if you want to disallow overlapping time ranges, use an exclusion constraint, based on a GiST index (GIN is not currently possibly). Details:

- [PostgreSQL EXCLUDE USING error: Data type integer has no default operator class](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37351/postgresql-exclude-using-error-data-type-integer-has-no-default-operator-class/37373#37373)
- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)
- [2 B-tree indices OR 1 GiST index on tsrange -- which will perform better?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59074/2-b-tree-indices-or-1-gist-index-on-tsrange-which-will-perform-better/59083#59083)
- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)

The last one also provides a clean solution for **enforcing `'[)'` boundaries**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64748/discussion-on-answer-by-erwin-brandstetter-writing-a-view-that-caches-to-another).