# Query result precedence if filter columns have values

Tags: postgresql, query, precedence

I have a table `"customer_config"` with these columns:

```
company (varchar)
warehouse (numeric)
section (numeric)
config_keyword (varchar)
config_value (varchar)
```

The two `config_*` columns can apply to an entire company (`warehouse` and `section` are null), an entire warehouse within a company (`section` is null), or a section within a warehouse.

So we could have a default row for the company, and then one or more rows that override a configuration value for a specific warehouse or warehouse & section.

I want to return only the most specific row for a given company, warehouse, and section. Something like this pseudocode:

```
results = select * from customer_config where (all match)
if results empty
    results = select * from customer_config where (company_code and warehouse match)
if results empty
    results = select * from customer_config where (company_code matches)
```

The most specific row shall take precedence.

###### Update

There can be multiple entries for the same `config_keyword` on the same level.
Is it also possible to return **multiple rows** for a single keyword?

Comment: A "list of values" would be just another string, and the given solutions work for that all the same. It's unclear what more you need. (Probably not a simple "list of values"?) Please ask your new question as *new question*. Don't change the nature of a question after answers have been given. A generous bounty does not change that principle.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Apologies for not being clear. By a list of values I mean that a single keyword could have multiple rows, each with a unique value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### "Only the most specific row"

While looking for a **single result row** (like your original question indicated):

This is a bit more verbose, but very clear and probably fastest if supported with an **index on `(company_code, warehouse, section)`** - like you should probably have anyway (depends on undisclosed info).

```
SELECT * FROM customer_config
WHERE  (company_code, warehouse, section) = ($1, $2, $3)

UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM customer_config
WHERE  (company_code, warehouse) = ($1, $2)

UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM customer_config
WHERE  company_code = $1
LIMIT  1;
```

Postgres will stop executing as soon as a row has been found. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, you'll see "never executed" for remaining sub-SELECTs.

Note that `LIMIT 1` applies to the whole query, not the last `SELECT`. (You'd need parentheses to change that.)
Similar:

- [How to force order of WHERE clauses in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184287/how-to-force-order-of-where-clauses-in-postgresql/184309#184309)

#### "All rows for the most specific match"

If multiple rows can exist on each level.

*Can* be solved with pure SQL of course. For instance with a chain of CTEs. But this custom PL/pgSQL function should be more efficient:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trade_volume (_company_code varchar, _warehouse numeric, _section numeric)
  RETURNS SETOF customer_config
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * FROM customer_config
   WHERE (company_code, warehouse, section) = ($1, $2, $3);

   IF FOUND THEN RETURN; END IF;
   
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * FROM customer_config
   WHERE (company_code, warehouse) = ($1, $2);

   IF FOUND THEN RETURN; END IF;
   
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * FROM customer_config
   WHERE  company_code = $1;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM trade_volume ('my_comany_code', 123456, 123);
```

Be sure to have **the index mentioned above**.

If the first query returns any rows, the function is done. The rest is not even planned. Etc.

Related:

- [Return default rows from a function when first SELECT does not return rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50380486/939860)
- [Writing a view that caches to another table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76744/writing-a-view-that-caches-to-another-table/76750#76750)

I made the function `PARALLEL SAFE` to allow parallelism in Postgres 14 or later. (Only relevant for *big* tables.) Quoting the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-14.html#id-1.11.6.7.5.9):

> Allow plpgsql's `RETURN QUERY` to execute its query using parallelism (Tom Lane)

Comment: Thanks, this looks almost exactly like what I need here, but I left out an important detail. It is possible for a keyword to have multiple records with different values. So some might be single key/value, but others could be a key/list of values. I modified your solution to `union` instead of `union all` as that seemed to give me unwanted duplicates, but the issue now is that it's evaluating the config_value as part of the union.

Comment: @secondbreakfast: I added a solution for your extended question. In any case, `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` would not make any sense for my query.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This looks similar to an idea I had of just doing it programmatically in the server code, but having it within the database like this with a single db call would be more efficient.

Comment: I know I'm asking a lot here....but due to constraints I am unable to create and rely on a function. Trying to wrap my head around chaining CTEs for a solution like you said...but I just can't figure it out. If someone could just point me in the direction of a blog post or something that gives a relevant example....I'd really appreciate it

Comment: wait nevermind, I think I got it! Used multiple CTEs combined with "union all" and "not exists" for each more specific CTE

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (config_keyword)
       config_keyword, config_value
FROM customer_config
WHERE company_code = $1
  AND coalesce(warehouse, $2) = $2
  AND coalesce(section, $3) = $3
ORDER BY config_keyword,
         section IS NULL,
         warehouse IS NULL;
```

`DISTINCT ON` will return the first row for each `config_keyword`, and results where `section` is not NULL will sort before results where `section` is NULL, because `FALSE < TRUE`. The same for `warehouse`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PostgreSQL, but in oracle it can be done with analitic functions to return multiple rows for a single keyword:

```
select * 
  from (
     select rank() over (order by section, warehouse, company_code ) rn, 
            c.* 
       from customer_config c
      where company_code = $1
        and coalesce(warehouse, $2) = $2
        and coalesce(section, $3) = $3
       )
 where rn = 1;
```