# Maximum sum() of overlapping ranges

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, window-functions, range-types

Essentially my question is: how does one do aggregate operations involving overlapping ranges in PostgreSQL 9.3 (or 9.4)? The specific problem I have at hand is that given a range, I want to find the maximum sum() of applicable overlapping ranges. A simple example:

```
create table event (
  event_id int primary key,
  event_type_id int not null,
  period tstzrange not null,
  quantity int not null
);

insert into event (event_id, event_type_id, period, quantity) values
(1, 1,'[2016-01-06 09:00:00+00,2016-01-08 17:00:00+00]',1),
(2, 1,'[2016-01-07 09:00:00+00,2016-01-07 11:00:00+00]',1),
(3, 1,'[2016-01-07 13:00:00+00,2016-01-07 17:00:00+00]',1),
(4, 2,'[2016-01-07 12:00:00+00,2016-01-07 17:00:00+00]',1);
```

Given a query with the following clauses:

```
select ... 
where event_type_id = 1
and period && '[2016-01-07 00:00:00+00,2016-01-07 23:59:00+00]'::tstzrange 
group by event_type_id
```

The desired result would be: 3, i.e. the maximum `sum(quantity)` where the ranges of the same `event_type_id` overlap within a given timestamp range.

Comment: All ranges are inclusive, and there are no constraints other than the PK and no indexes, since I wanted to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The task as I understand it

Pick rows from a table where the `period` overlaps with a given time frame. Determine distinct ranges of overlapping periods within that set and return the greatest `sum(quantity)` from any range.

Requires Postgres **9.2**+, since there are no range types in older versions.

#### Assumptions

- "Overlapping" is meant in a cascading manner, like tiles on a traditional roof: those are "overlapping" (rainproof), though the highest tile does not directly overlap with the lowest.
- All values in `period` have *inclusive* bounds (`[]`). Else you have to adjust for exclusive bounds. (The range of the *input parameter* can still have arbitrary bounds.)
- We filter for exactly ***one*** `event_type_id`. Else you have to add `PARTITION BY event_type_id` to the window definition.
- `quantity` is an `integer`. Else you have to adjust for the type in calculations.
- Quantities for overlapping periods are counted **fully**, even if parts of the period are outside your given time frame.
- Even works for duplicates on `(event_type_id, period)`.

### Best performance with a single subquery

This should be dynamite.

```
SELECT running_sum - lag(running_sum, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY p_start) AS sum_quantity
FROM  (
   SELECT lower(period) AS p_start
        ,(sum(quantity)                      OVER w)::int AS running_sum
        , lead(lower(period), 1, 'infinity') OVER w
                        > max(upper(period)) OVER w AS range_end
   FROM   event
   WHERE  event_type_id = 1
   AND    period && '[2016-01-01 0:0+0,2016-01-10 0:0+0]'::tstzrange 
   WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY lower(period))
   ) sub
WHERE  range_end
ORDER  BY 1 DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

All three window functions in the subquery can use the same window. This avoids additional sort operations and should be fastest.

### Verbose CTE variant with more explanation

**Same query**, just more verbose and slower, since CTEs materialize derived tables and pose as optimization barriers.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
   SELECT quantity
        , lower(period) AS p_start
        , upper(period) AS p_end
   FROM   event
   WHERE  event_type_id = 1
   AND    period && '[2016-01-01 0:0+0,2016-01-10 0:0+0]'::tstzrange
   )
,    cte2 AS (
   SELECT (sum(quantity)               OVER w)::int AS running_sum
        , lead(p_start, 1, 'infinity') OVER w               -- next start ..
                          > max(p_end) OVER w AS range_end  -- .. after last end
        , p_start, p_end
   FROM   cte1
   WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY p_start)
   )
SELECT running_sum - lag(running_sum, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY p_start) AS sum_quantity
                    -- subtract the previous sum to get the sum of this range
     , p_end::text
FROM   cte2
WHERE  range_end    -- only rows at the end of each range
ORDER  BY 1 DESC    -- biggest sum first
LIMIT  1;           -- only return the winner
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q3imPtQ_)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a596e/12) for Postgres 9.3</sub>

You need an index for this to be fast with big tables. The best option would be a **GiST index** on `(event_type_id, period)`. Details:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)

### Explanation

Filter rows that match your conditions, then sort by the start of the time range (`lower(period)`) and calculate:

1. A running sum of quantity (`running_sum`).
2. The start of the next period: (`lead(lower(period), 1, 'infinity')`).
   Defaults to 'infinity' for the last row to include the last range.
3. The latest end of any period so far `max(upper(period))`.

If *2.* is later than *3.* it's the end of a (sub-)range (`range_end`).

In the outer `SELECT` filter rows with `range_end` and subtract the previous total to get the sum for the range. `ORDER BY` that result and return the first (`LIMIT 1`) greatest `sum_quantity`. Voilá.

#### Aside

To select all of Jan 7th, 2016, the clean expression is:

```
'[2016-01-07 00:00:00+00,2016-01-08 00:00:00+00)'::tstzrange
```

Not:

```
'[2016-01-07 00:00:00+00,2016-01-07 23:59:00+00]'::tstzrange
```

Details:

- [PostgreSQL splitting time range into days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19457463/939860)

Since the default precision of timestamp values is 6 decimal digits (microseconds resolution), you *could* also use:

```
'[2016-01-07 00:00:00+00,2016-01-07 23:59:59.999999+00]'::tstzrange
```

But that's messy and depends on an implementation detail that might change (even if unlikely). It's *not* subject to rounding errors, since timestamps are stored as integer values in modern Postgres:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Comment: This doesn't correctly account for multiple overlaps. I'll use digits instead of dates for brevity: with ranges A: `[1, 5]`, B: `[2, 6]`, C: `[3, 8]`, D: `[7, 9]`, in the interval `[3, 5]` there are three overlapping ranges (A, B and C), only two in `[5, 6]` (B & C) and again for `[7, 8]` (C & D). Your query sums the values of A, B, C and D, because only for D is `range_end` true. In reality D should never be summed, it never overlaps with A and B.

Comment: @Martin: In reality, D is excluded a priori by the predicate `WHERE  period && '[3,5]'::int4range` and can never be summed. Ignoring the outer range, the definition of "overlapping" seems to be ambiguous. This answer understands it in a cascading manner, like tiles on a traditional roof: those are "overlapping" (rainproof), though the highest tile never overlaps with the lowest tile.

Comment: Agreed, the definition of 'overlapping' is ambiguous. I was looking for the specific interval with which the largest number of rows overlap. I found my answer at [How to get maximum number of concurrent events in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46908045); a union of start and end times with +1 and -1 counters lets you aggregate to a measure of concurrency.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I clarified accordingly above to avoid future misunderstandings. Your task is subtly different in nature. At a closer look, your task is also subtly different from [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46908045), as that checks for the point in time with the most overlapping ranges. Your problem is harder, looking for the *range* with the most overlapping ranges.

Comment: My output requirements didn't actually include the interval end, only the start, so I was ambiguous as well. My apologies!