# Fastest query for distinct IDs in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: postgresql, count, performance, distinct, postgresql-performance

I have this table in PostgreSQL 9.4:

```
CREATE TABLE user_operations( 
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    operation_id integer, 
    user_id integer )
```

The table consists of `~1000-2000` different operations each of which corresponds to some subset (consisting of approximately `80000-120000` elements each) of the set `S` of all users:

```
S = {1, 2, 3, ... , 122655}
```

Parameters:

```
work_mem = 128MB
table_size = 880MB
```

I also have an index on the `operation_id`.

***QUESTION:*** What would be the most optimal plan for querying all distinct `user_id` for a significant part of the `operation_id` set (20%-60%) like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_operation WHERE operation_id < 500
```

**It's possible to create more indexes on the table**. Currently, the plan for the query is:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=196173.56..196347.14 rows=17358 width=4) (actual time=1227.408..1359.947 rows=598336 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on user_operation  (cost=46392.24..189978.17 rows=2478155 width=4) (actual time=233.163..611.182 rows=2518122 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (operation_id < 500)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx  (cost=0.00..45772.70 rows=2478155 width=0) (actual time=230.432..230.432 rows=2518122 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (operation_id < 500)
```

Is such query plan really optimal in such circumstances? I mean, I'm not sure about correctness of using `Bitmap Heap Scan`. I'll appreciate any references to relevant articles.

Comment: If my question seems too broad, please let me know what kind of paramters I should add to it to make it more specific.

Comment: What's your problem with the bitmap heap scan? :)  Anyway, the numbers you have above differ significantly from those in the plan.  Why is it so?  Also, an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` could possibly tell a bit more about the optimalness of your plan.  What is you expectiation (time-wise)?  There are chances that an index on `(operation_id, user_id)` would result in a somewhat more efficient query.

Comment: @dezso I've tried that index.The planner won't even consider it.

Comment: That you don't know :)  It just didn't choose it.  OK, this is nitpicking :)  Did you `ANALYZE` the table?  Also, after `SET enable_bitmapscan TO off;`, does it show up in the plan?  Is it worse or better?

Comment: @dezso Yes, I ran `ANALYZE` on the able after creating the index. About, Hmmm, maybe. But I really don't see how that index may help the query, we don't restrict it by `user_id`...

Comment: You don't restrict, but doing a `DISTINCT` on it.  My idea is that a single index-only scan would be enough to collect the data for the aggregation - lowering the I/O needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would be the most optimal plan for querying all distinct `user_id`
>   for a significant part of the `operation_id` set (20%-60%).

Use a recursive query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (  -- parentheses are required
   SELECT user_id
   FROM   user_operations
   WHERE  operation_id < 500
   ORDER  BY user_id
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT u.user_id
   FROM   cte, LATERAL (
      SELECT user_id
      FROM   user_operations
      WHERE  operation_id < 500
      AND    user_id > cte.user_id  -- lateral reference
      ORDER  BY user_id
      LIMIT  1
      ) u
   )
TABLE cte;
```

In combination with an index on `(user_id, operation_id)` - *columns in that order*. I expect index scans that filter on the second column. Reasonably accurate table statistics are important so Postgres knows it will only have to skip a few rows in the index to find the next `user_id`. Generally, one *might* want to increase the statistics target for `operation_id` in particular:

```
ALTER TABLE user_operations ALTER operation_id SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

Since there are only `~1000-2000 different operations`, this may not even be necessary, but it's a small price to pay.

Details:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)

**If** the predicate `operation_id < 500` is stable (always the same), make that a partial index on just `(user_id)` instead:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON user_operations (user_id) WHERE operation_id < 500;
```

Then statistics on `operation_id` are not relevant to this query any more.

Even if the predicate is not stable, there may be ways to optimize - depending on the full range of possible conditions and value frequencies.

Performance should be ... *delicious*.

I optimized the technique in this related answer on SO (with detailed explanation):

- **[Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)**

**If** you have a separate `users` table and a large part of all users can be found in your sample, even faster query styles are possible. Details in the linked answer.

Comment: May I ask you a question related to the algorithm you proposed. Since, btree indexes tree traversal have approximately constant time complexity (because of a number of the tree levels grows very slow), can we say that the "complexity of the query" is approximately `O(N)` where `N` is a number of all distinct `user_id`s. In fact, it starts slowly, but works very well if the `many-to-many table` has a very large size (much more than the count of all distinct `user_id`s).

Comment: @St.Antario: Yes, approximately. In addition to the points you already mentioned, total number of rows and total table size are also relevant (to a lesser extent). If you exhaust RAM limits, performance takes a hit. If index-only scans are possible (like probably in this case), only the size of the index matters.