# how to optimize multiple unions for the same table with different condition into a single query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Environment : PostgreSQL v10.6 (AWS RDS instance)
For the given table:

```
CREATE temp TABLE lve
    ("fin" timestamptz, "vehiculo" int, "equipo" int)
;
    
INSERT INTO lve
    ("fin", "vehiculo", "equipo")
VALUES
    ('2021-12-01 00:00:00', 1, 888),
    (NULL, 3, 888),
    ('2021-05-01 00:00:00', 2, 888),
    ('2021-11-05 00:00:00', 10, 333),
    (NULL, 9, 333),
    ('2021-09-05 00:00:00', 5, 333)
;
```

I need the last record (by '*fin*' column) where '*fin*' is not null, for **every value in a given list** of '*equipo*'.

For a single, given '*equipo*', this query works:

```
select * from lve
where equipo = 333 and fin is not null
order by fin desc
limit 1
```

for two '*equipo*' ,  with a UNION I can get my desired result:

```
(select * from lve
where equipo = 333 and fin is not null
order by fin desc
limit 1)
union 
(select * from lve
where equipo = 888 and fin is not null
order by fin desc
limit 1);
```

result:

| fin | vehiculo | equipo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-05 00:00:00.000 -0300 | 10 | 333 |
| 2021-12-01 00:00:00.000 -0300 | 1 | 888 |

But since in reality the table contains much more data for many others vehiculo/equipo and I can have a list with N '*equipo*' to query for, it's not optimal to continue adding multiple UNIONs manually.

Is there a way that I can rewrite this into a single query where i can just pass the list/array of given '*equipo*' (888, 333, nnn) ?

PD: My plan B is to create a function that returns my desired record for a single '*equipo*' and then use that with an array, but I really want to know if this can be done in the way I'm asking.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DISTINCT ON vs ROW\_NUMBER() for getting a row with a maximum value of a group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118882/distinct-on-vs-row-number-for-getting-a-row-with-a-maximum-value-of-a-group)

Comment: @mustaccio I fail to see how it applies to my case. Could you please help me with an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row_number() to order by fin for each equipo and then choose the first/last from there:

```
select fin, vehiculo, equipo
from (
  select fin, vehiculo, equipo
     , row_number() over (partition by equipo order by fin desc) as rn
  from  lve
  where fin is not null
) as t
where rn = 1;

fin vehiculo    equipo
2021-11-05 00:00:00+00  10  333
2021-12-01 00:00:00+00  1   888
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a4f235fb262858ede4cc6b5fa7fef28a)

Comment: and then i can filter my list with 'equipo in ( ... )', great!

Comment: Probably most efficient to do that filtering in the inner select