# Grouping data by year based on two timestamp columns

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, time, set-returning-functions

My `data` table has the following columns:

```
id INTEGER, name TEXT, created TIMESTAMP, deleted TIMESTAMP
```

I want to product a report of the count of each `name` (which can appear several times in the table) that is active each year.
(also, the `deleted` timestamp may be null, if it's currently still active).

So far I’ve managed to do this by manually entering the years in a long list of union statements (see below). I’m sure there’s a better way! And I have many more similar queries to perform. I tried to create a PL/pgSQL function, but couldn’t figure out how to get the year as a variable and also how to get the correct output. I would be very happy with a statement, or PL/pgSQL function to achieve this.

```
((select '2016' yr, name, count(*) from data
where (((deleted - '2016-01-01'::timestamp) > '0 secs') or (deleted is null))
and (created - '2016-01-01'::timestamp) <= '0 secs'
group by name
order by count desc)
union all
((select '2015' yr, name, count(*) from data
where (((deleted - '2015-01-01'::timestamp) > '0 secs') or (deleted is null))
and (created - '2015-01-01'::timestamp) <= '0 secs'
group by name
order by count desc)
etc..
```

I got the years using:

```
select distinct date_part('year',created) from data order by date_part('year',created);
```

And then manually entered them in the very long union statement. (In my case 2007-2016!)

Comment: PL/SQL is the procedural language of Oracle. I assume you mean PL/pgSQL? And *always* provide your version of Postgres, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) in a `LATERAL` join (Postgres 9.3+) and [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), this can be short & simple:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM yr)::text AS year, name, count(*) AS ct
FROM   data
     , generate_series(date_trunc('year', created)  -- LATERAL join
                     , COALESCE(deleted, localtimestamp)
                     , interval '1 year') yr
GROUP  BY yr, name
ORDER  BY yr, ct DESC;
```

That's all. Returns results for *all* years between the earliest `created` and the current year.
The trick is to generate one row for each year the base row overlaps with, before aggregating.

Alternative:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM yr) AS year, d.name, count(*) AS count
FROM   generate_series ((SELECT date_trunc('year', min(created)) FROM data)
                       , localtimestamp, interval '1 year') yr
JOIN   data d ON d.created < yr::timestamp + interval '1 year'
            AND (d.deleted > yr::timestamp OR d.deleted IS NULL)
GROUP  BY yr, d.name
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC;
```

This generates the whole range of years before joining. May be more convenient to compute numbers for a manual selection of years.

Related:

- [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15305292/939860)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

If you need to optimize performance for a *small* set of years out of a much bigger table, a GiST index on a `tsrange` type would be an option:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)