# Efficient predictable ordering in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, execution-plan, index-tuning, query-performance

I have a large table of locations. I would like to efficient paginate though the table. I had previously being using an `OFFSET` approach however the size of the table made that approach unusable. So I am now trying a cursor approach using the location `id`.

In order to ensure consistent ordering for cases where a user has 2 rows with identical `timestamp`, I am also ordering by `id`.

```
SELECT  *
FROM locations
WHERE
  user_id = 1
ORDER BY timestamp desc, id
LIMIT 100;
```

However after adding `id` to the `ORDER BY`, the query has become slow. It is now doing a `Seq Scan` which takes ~20 seconds.

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=502534.86..502535.11 rows=100 width=152) (actual 
time=22822.113..22822.142 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=502534.86..515512.80 rows=5191175 width=152) (actual time=22822.110..22822.133 rows=100 loops=1)
        Sort Key: ""timestamp"" DESC, id"
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 51kB
    ->  Seq Scan on locations  (cost=0.00..304131.89 rows=5191175 width=152) (actual time=1.603..21284.908 rows=5169237 loops=1)
          Filter: (user_id = 1)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 3048468
Planning time: 0.204 ms
Execution time: 22822.194 ms
```

Timestamp collisions are edge cases and `id` is a primary key. So why does the execution plan require a `Seq Scan`?

For context

```
SELECT indexdef
FROM pg_indexes
WHERE tablename = 'locations'
```

results

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX locations_pkey ON locations USING btree (id)
CREATE INDEX index_locations_on_user_id_and_timestamp ON locations USING btree (user_id, "timestamp")
CREATE INDEX index_locations_on_user_id_and_point ON locations USING gist (user_id, point)
CREATE INDEX index_locations_on_user_id ON locations USING btree (user_id)
CREATE INDEX index_locations_on_user_id_and_timestamp ON locations USING btree (user_id, "timestamp")
CREATE INDEX index_locations_on_user_id_and_timestamp_and_id ON locations USING btree (user_id, "timestamp", id)
```

Comment: Care to add the table and index definitions? You're probably missing an appropriate index. And do you really need `SELECT *`?

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio, I added the table indexes for context. And yes, the actual query only retrieves the columns needed. It's fast with `ORDER BY timestamp desc` but super slow with `ORDER BY timestamp desc, id` as is requires a `Seq Scan`. I'm not sure why it requires a `Seq Scan` when `id` is a primary key. I even tried adding an extra index which includes `(user_id, timestamp, id)`. Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Can you show the `EXPLAIN` of the fast version of the query, with only the `ORDER BY timestamp desc`? I assume that one is using one of your indexes which the slow query is not, not sure exactly why yet.

Comment: Oh, I just recognized what your problem likely is. An index on `(user_id asc, timestamp asc, id asc)` (all are `asc` implicitly if not specified) can't handle a `WHERE user_id=1` and then an `ORDER BY timestamp desc, id`; for that you need `(user_id asc, timestamp desc, id asc)`. I'm doing some checking to confirm, but try creating the index with `desc` on the `timestamp` column.

Comment: Just to clarify something about the use case, is it normal for a single user's id to match so much of the table? It appears to be a significant fraction of the table in the `EXPLAIN`, which is changing the query plan relative to what I'd normally expect.

Comment: @AdamKG: You nailed it, I am pretty sure. Add an *answer* instead of just a comment. This related answer has detailed explanation: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/3684

Comment: @AdamKG, spot on! It was the direction of the index. I added `DESC` to the `id` order and it finished in 43ms :D Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `INDEX(timestamp DESC, id ASC)`?

Or, try `ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id DESC` .