# Time series index range contains operator (reverse)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, range-types, time-series-database

Hi I am trying to optimise the a timestamp range contains `<@` query for Postgres 12

I have done a bit of reading [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING)  and discovered only GiST and SP-GiST indexes support this operator. However, I can't add one of these ( I tink I would need to add one to the heartrate table - see Schema below, but that is not a range type...).

My question is similar to this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/perform-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524) which also indicate I will need a GiST index. However, they are the other way around, eg the column they have a single timestamp and want to return from a table of `tsrange`s all records that are contained. I have a table of timestamps and want to join it to a table of tsranges

For a bit of context for my schema, I have a collection of heartrates in the real dataset sampled ~1/3seconds, and a list of songs I have listen to, and when. I would like to query things like

- `avg(heartrate)` for a particular `track`  and `artist`
- `avg(heartrate)` for a particular `artist`
- etc.

### Schema

> ```
> create table heartrate (
>     "time"  timestamp primary key ,
>     value float
> )
> ;
>
> CREATE INDEX ON heartrate ("time", value);
> -- CREATE INDEX ON heartrate USING GIST ("time", value); can't do as "time" is not a range column.
> -- one gets the following error: 
> --- ERROR: data type timestamp without time zone has no default operator class for access method "gist" Hint: You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
>
>
> create table song_play(
>     track       TEXT      NOT NULL,
>     artist      TEXT      NOT NULL,
>     play        tsrange not null
> )
> ;
> CREATE INDEX ON song_play(track, artist);
>
>
> INSERT INTO heartrate("time", value)
> SELECT d, 60+60*random()
> FROM   generate_series('2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, '5 min'::interval)  d
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO song_play(track,artist, play)
> SELECT case when random() > 0.5 then 'a' when random() > 0.5 then 'b' else 'c' end 
> , case when random() > 0.5 then 'a' when random() > 0.5 then 'b' else 'c' end
> , tsrange(d, d+ (((random()*3+1)::text|| 'min')::interval))
> FROM   generate_series('2015-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval)  d
> ;
>
> EXPLAIN  SELECT sp.track, sp.artist, avg(h.value) FROM song_play sp left join heartrate h ON h.time <@ sp.play where sp.track='a' and sp.artist='b' GROUP BY sp.track, sp.artist;
> ```

Which results in the following:

> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> 525889 rows affected
>
> 1827 rows affected
>
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                                                 |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | GroupAggregate  (cost=0.28..14689.24 rows=1 width=72)                                                      |
> |   Group Key: sp.track, sp.artist                                                                           |
> |   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.28..14685.28 rows=526 width=72)                                       |
> |         Join Filter: (h."time" <@ sp.play)                                                                 |
> |         ->  Index Scan using song_play_track_artist_idx on song_play sp  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=96) |
> |               Index Cond: ((track = 'a'::text) AND (artist = 'b'::text))                                   |
> |         ->  Seq Scan on heartrate h  (cost=0.00..8102.55 rows=525955 width=16)                             |
> ```

Note: the above plan results in A **Full** seq scan of the heartrate table, the largest table - not ideal at all!

I then decided to create the following function to see if it would help speed up queries. It converts a range eg `tsrange('2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-02 00:00:00')` to a conditional query eg `field >= 2020-01-01 00:00:00 and field < '2020-01-02 00:00:00'` .

essentially the same as the `<@` contains operator.

And it seems to work! Although this is only helpful for looking up a particular `song_play`'s heartrate... not all of a `track` / `artist`'s `song_play`'s heartrates

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION range_to_conditional(range anyrange, field text)
>     RETURNS text
>     LANGUAGE SQL
>     IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
> $$
> SELECT case
>            when isempty(range) then 'false'
>            when upper_inf(range) and lower_inf(range) then 'true'
>            when upper_inf(range) then case
>                                           when lower_inc(range) then format(' %L <= %I ', lower(range), field)
>                                           else format(' %L < %I ', lower(range), field)
>                end
>            when lower_inf(range) then case
>                                           when upper_inc(range) then format(' %L >= %I ', upper(range), field)
>                                           else format(' %L > %I ', upper(range), field)
>                end
>            else
>                case
>                    when lower_inc(range) and upper_inc(range)
>                        then format(' %1$L <= %3$I AND %2$L >= %3$I ', lower(range), upper(range), field)
>                    when lower_inc(range)
>                        then format(' %1$L <= %3$I AND %2$L > %3$I ', lower(range), upper(range), field)
>                    when upper_inc(range)
>                        then format(' %1$L < %3$I AND %2$L >= %3$I ', lower(range), upper(range), field)
>                    else format(' %1$L < %3$I AND %2$L > %3$I ', lower(range), upper(range), field)
>                    end
>            end
> $$
>
>
> ;
>
>
> create function avg_heartrate(sp song_play)
> returns double precision as $$
> DECLARE
>     retval double precision ;
> BEGIN
>     EXECUTE format('select avg(h.value) from heartrate h where %s',  range_to_conditional(sp.play, 'time'))
>     INTO STRICT retval;
>     RETURN retval;
> END
> $$
>     LANGUAGE plpgsql stable;
>
> SELECT sp.track, sp.artist, sp.play, avg_heartrate(sp) from song_play sp where  sp.track='a' and sp.artist='b' limit 10;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> track | artist | play                                                 | avg_heartrate     
> :---- | :----- | :--------------------------------------------------- | :-----------------
> a     | b      | ["2015-01-03 00:00:00","2015-01-03 00:03:42.413608") | 78.93074469582096 
> a     | b      | ["2015-01-10 00:00:00","2015-01-10 00:01:32.299356") | 83.89127804586359 
> a     | b      | ["2015-01-11 00:00:00","2015-01-11 00:03:24.722083") | 62.333722293527885
> a     | b      | ["2015-01-19 00:00:00","2015-01-19 00:01:14.845757") | 77.65872734128969 
> a     | b      | ["2015-01-30 00:00:00","2015-01-30 00:01:40.991165") | 102.88233680407437
> a     | b      | ["2015-02-06 00:00:00","2015-02-06 00:03:51.264716") | 70.34797302970127 
> a     | b      | ["2015-02-13 00:00:00","2015-02-13 00:01:23.358657") | 62.91734005187344 
> a     | b      | ["2015-02-25 00:00:00","2015-02-25 00:02:04.856602") | 115.45533419257616
> a     | b      | ["2015-02-28 00:00:00","2015-02-28 00:02:46.800728") | 117.39846990343175
> a     | b      | ["2015-03-18 00:00:00","2015-03-18 00:02:54.893186") | 68.1618921408235
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fe23dbced7ea5a3005dd4dd2bb4d6c76)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the join condition from

```
ON h.time <@ sp.play
```

to

```
ON h.time >= lower(sp.play) AND h.time < upper(sp.play)
```

(if your ranges are open at the right end, else use different inequality operators).

Then the nested loop join can use a regular b-tree index on `heartrate(time)` to speed up the inner query.

Comment: Thanks this suits my needs, so I will mark it as accepted. But I was curious what you would do if not all ranges have the same inclusive/exclusive bounds. eg some `[)` whereas others `[]`

Comment: That would probably not work, but it is an unusual scenario.