# Can PostgreSQL use indexes to expedite count(distinct) queries?

Tags: postgresql, index, count, distinct

Consider the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id SERIAL,
  some_integer INT
);

INSERT INTO test (some_integer)
SELECT FLOOR(RANDOM()*100000) from generate_series(1,100000) s(i);

CREATE INDEX some_integer_idx ON test (some_integer);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT some_integer) from test;
```

It returns the following query plan:

```
                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1693.00..1693.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=26.343..26.344 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..1443.00 rows=100000 width=4) (actual time=0.011..7.282 rows=100000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.052 ms
 Execution Time: 26.365 ms
(4 rows)
```

I was surprised it still did a sequential scan on test. Wouldn't it be faster to simply count the number of rows in the index?

Comment: The number of rows in your index = the number of rows in the table, so no reason it would be faster in that regard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a separate entry in a B-tree index for *every* row, for duplicates, too. So we can never *"simply count the number of rows in the index*". There are as many index rows to read and aggregate as there are table rows.

[Index deduplication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-implementation.html#BTREE-DEDUPLICATION) in Postgres 13 or later can compress duplicates, offering more potential for optimization, but the principal logic stands (1 row, 1 index tuple). See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Since a B-tree index is typically smaller than its table, an index-only scan is still an attractive option. But that adds some overhead: checking the visibility map, heap fetches for data pages that are not "all-visible". And indexes tend to bloat more than tables (voiding the initial advantage). And [indexes default to `fillfactor` 90](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#INDEX-RELOPTION-FILLFACTOR), while tables default to `fillfactor` 100. And the [visibility map](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/storage-vm.html) has to be up to date to begin with - the table has to be vacuumed enough. Add `VACUUM ANALYZE` to your test for a start.

Your test table has 8 bytes of data, which is the smallest row size possible. And you create very few duplicates. So **very** little to gain from an index-only scan, even under perfect conditions. Postgres doesn't even try.

Add a payload column to grow the table row, and create some more duplicates and, voilá, we see an **index-only scan**:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id serial
, some_integer int
, payload text
);

INSERT INTO test (some_integer, payload)
SELECT trunc(random() * 10000)  -- fewer distinct values, some dupes
     , 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit'  -- bigger row !!
FROM   generate_series(1,100000) s;

CREATE INDEX some_integer_idx ON test (some_integer);
```

```
VACUUM ANALYZE test;
```

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(DISTINCT some_integer) FROM test;
```

```
Aggregate  (cost=2210.29..2210.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=25.763..25.764 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using some_integer_idx on test  (cost=0.29..1960.29 rows=100000 width=4) (actual time=0.030..12.562 rows=100000 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.184 ms
Execution Time: 25.891 ms
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9a82d48698431b1d384579ccd61beb1a)*

The benefit grows with the relative size handicap table >> index, the percentage of duplicates, and the portion of "all-visible" data pages (updated visibility map).

#### Optimization for many duplicates

Now, if **index skip scans** were already implemented, the index could be put to good use for cases with **many duplicates** (unlike your example), even without payload column. [But we are not there, yet (Postgres 15)](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/19/1741/).

Until then we can **emulate** an index skip scan:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT some_integer AS i
   FROM   test
   ORDER  BY 1
   LIMIT  1
   )
   
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT t.some_integer
           FROM   test t
           WHERE  t.some_integer > c.i
           ORDER  BY 1
           LIMIT  1)
   FROM   cte c
   WHERE  c.i IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT count(i) FROM cte;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a70748f64afd21223dd29ef3f8772341)*

Much faster. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)
- [How to get the second highest value per group?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303297/how-to-get-the-second-highest-value-per-group/303320#303320)
- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66894500/939860)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

Comment: Fantastic answer! And yes, there aren't necessarily "many" duplicates in the current example, depending on how you define "many," but the critical point is that the behavior is the same even if _every_ value in `some_integer` is the same. Your answer explains why that is brilliantly!