# Very slow simple PostgreSQL query on RDS

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, performance, postgresql-performance

I seem to be getting very slow queries on a medium sized RDS box (db.m3.medium, 3.7gb ram).

This is across a table of 4,152,928 rows..

```
select sum(some_field) c
from pages
where pages.some_id=123
and pages.first_action_at > '2014-01-01 00:00:00 +1000'
```

Total runtime: 45031 ms.
Locally, I have around 1.1million rows, and the same query takes about 450ms..

Here's the query plan, from explain:

```
Aggregate  (cost=475640.59..475640.60 rows=1 width=4)
   ->  Seq Scan on pages  (cost=0.00..475266.07 rows=149809 width=4)
         Filter: ((first_action_at > '2014-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) 
                AND (some_id = 447))
```

Here's the response from explain analyze:

```
 Aggregate  (cost=475641.74..475641.76 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=42419.717..42419.718 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on pages  (cost=0.00..475267.22 rows=149810 width=4) (actual time=0.013..42265.908 rows=141559 loops=1)
    Filter: ((first_action_at > '2014-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (some_id = 447))
    Rows Removed by Filter: 4011369
```

Total runtime: 42419.772 ms

For reference, 141559 rows are part of the sum().

The current indexes I have are:

```
:some_id
:some_id, :first_action_at
```

`work_mem` was previously set to 1 mb (RDS default). I've just changed this to 18 mb.

Edit: Seems to be resolved by upping `work_mem` as well as added the second index above, speed is now around 800 ms.

Comment: How many rows qualify for that condition? Are statistics up-to-date? If it's a very selective condition an index access might be ok, if lots of rows qualify it should go for a full table scan.

Comment: Could you also show the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE ? And what are the settings for work_mem ?

Comment: Ok, I realized I had my local response from explain there, I've updated it, along with the above data. ~141k rows are returned as part of the query. I've also added explain analyze. I'll find out the settings for work_mem now

Comment: Is it just me or there is no even a single mention about any indexes created for the table? Presumably it must be `(some_id, first_action_at)` or even `(some_id, first_action_at, some_field)`

Comment: @zerkms, erk, sorry about that, updating post now

Comment: Just a side note: if you already have `(some_id, first_action_at)` index, then an index that covers the single `(some_id)` column is redundant.

Comment: yup, thanks @zerkms, I think you solved it.. I only just added the second index and it's now down to around 2seconds.. I think that, and changing the work_mem value seems to have resolved 90% of it, thanks

Comment: I don't assume Redshift supports index-only reads, so adding `somefield` to the index `(some_id, first_action_at, some_field)` would only make it a bit slower. `(some_id, first_action_at)` is it.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: I'm sure OP was referring to the `(some_id, first_action_at)` as the second index though.

Comment: Postgres can use just the first column of a multicolumn index when needed, so the second index makes the first redundant. Without knowing the distribution of your data, I can't guess whether your index is better than one on `(first_action_at, some_id)` and it is worth making the obvious experiment.

Comment: Wait, this is Amazon RDS, not Redshift, right? What is your *actual* version of Postgres? What do you get for `SELECT version()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Matching index

After re-reading your question I realized you are not running Amazon Redshift, but Amazon RDS, which seems to be running unsullied Postgres, at least [according to the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html):

> Amazon RDS supports DB instances running several versions of
> PostgreSQL. Currently we support PostgreSQL versions 9.3.1, 9.3.2, and 9.3.3.

This would mean you have [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) at your disposal. If you meet some preconditions (basically if `vacuum` can keep up with write operations) and if `some_field` is not updated to often and reasonably small (which seems to be the case for a numeric column), the perfect index would include `some_field` in last position (like [@zerkms first mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69835/very-slow-simple-postgresql-query-on-rds#comment126055_69835)):

```
CREATE INDEX ON pages(some_id, first_action_at, some_field);
```

Note that `some_id` should come *before* `first_action_at`, because it is typically more efficient to have columns with equality checks first and ranges later. Details:
[Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/multicolumn-index-and-performance/33220#33220)

If you don't see "index-only scan" in `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, the last column is just ballast and better left away:

```
CREATE INDEX ON pages(some_id, first_action_at);
```

(Like you have now, according to your question update.)

Either way, another index on just `(some_id)` only offers very little over this multicolumn index:
[Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

#### Server configuration

All the [usual advice for slow queries and proper server configuration](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions) applies and a `work_mem` setting of 1 MB is much too low for a DB with millions of rows. But this particular setting should not be crucial for this particular query, since `work_mem` is ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY)):

> memory to be used by internal sort operations and hash tables.

Neither applies here.