# Composite multicolumn index for geopoint range and numeric range query

Tags: postgresql, index, gist-index, gin-index

I am building an app where the server needs to select rows based on some criteria/filters. One of them is the location of the user and the radius at which the user want's to see posts and other filters such date range and filter for a value of another column. This is going to be for an ad-hoc event discovery app.

I have read about PostGIS, its `geometry`,`geography` types and I know there is a native `point` datatype. Based on [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33220/91722) answer I understood that it is better to order from equality to range columns, even though I feel like geo point column should be the first.

Suppose the following few rows of a simplified events table (disregard the validity position data):

```
id  event_title                  event_position   event_type  is_public  start_date
    (varchar)                    (point lat/lon)  (smallint)  (boolean)  (timestamptz)
--  ---------------------------  ---------------  ---------   ---------  ----
 1  "John's Party"               (122,35)         0           0          2020-07-05
 2  "Revolution then Starbucks"  (123,30)         1           1          2020-07-06
 3  "Study for math exam"        (120,36)         2           1          2020-07-07
 4  "Party after exam"           (120,36)         1           1          2020-07-08
 5  "Hiking next to the city"    (95,40)          3           1          2020-07-09
 6  "Football match"             (-42,31)         4           1          2020-07-10
```

Imagine the table contains several thousand records at least, obviously not only 6.

So in this table a user would be able to query public events close to (122,34) by 100km (suppose first three rows fall into this area) and of event types 0, 1 or 2 falling between dates 2020-07-05 and 2020-07-07. The user would get the rows with ID 2 and 3.

This is the query I want to optimize with an appropriate index. My question is, how is it possible to create such an index? I thought about GiST or GIN index but not sure how these could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[@jjanes' answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742161/6585695) that I accepted

> With the help of the [btree_gist extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html), you can include the
> event_type and start_date columns into the GiST index along with the
> event_position.  However, the event_type won't be very useful in the
> index as long as the restriction clause is something like `event_type in (0, 1, 2)`.  (But if the list only contains one element, it will be
> rewritten into an equality, and in that case it can use that column in
> the index efficiently.)  So using the other two columns would be my
> starting point.  I would put the usually more selective one first.  If
> you are going to leave past events in the table rather than clearing
> them out, then the date is probably going to eventually be the more
> selective one.
>
> If the location condition is not very selective at all (e.g. most of
> your events are in NYC, and most of your users are in NYC, and almost
> everything is within 100km of almost everything else), then you might
> want a different approach.  Just make a default BTREE index on
> `(event_type, start_date)`.  Unlike GiST, such a BTREE can effectively
> use a condition like `event_type in (0, 1, 2)` along with `AND start_date between x and y`.
>
> I don't think that there is a fundamental reason GiST can't use the
> in-list effectively while BTREE can.  Maybe that will be fixed for
> GiST in some future version.