# Efficient query plan for selecting all data duplicated on several columns

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql

The flavour in question is PostgreSQL, but it is a generic enough query pattern that your techniques for optimising against other RDBMs should help as well.

The purpose of the query is to show all records from a table that are duplicated along several columns (user selectable).

```
  SELECT usr_id,
         team_name, team_streetno, team_city,
         usr_firstname, usr_lastname, usr_jobtitle, usr_department, usr_email
    FROM team c
    JOIN usr p on p.team_id=c.team_id
    JOIN
    (
        select match_firstname, match_lastname, match_jobtitle, match_department, match_email ,
               match_team_name, match_team_streetno, match_team_city 
          FROM usr
          JOIN team on usr.team_id=team.team_id
      GROUP BY match_firstname, match_lastname, match_jobtitle, match_department, match_email,
               match_team_name, match_team_streetno, match_team_city
        HAVING count(usr_id)>1
    ) AS sub
      ON sub.match_team_name = c.match_team_name
     AND sub.match_team_streetno = c.match_team_streetno
     AND sub.match_team_city = c.match_team_city
     AND sub.match_firstname = p.match_firstname
     AND sub.match_lastname = p.match_lastname
     AND sub.match_jobtitle = p.match_jobtitle
     AND sub.match_department = p.match_department
     AND sub.match_email = p.match_email
ORDER BY usr_firstname, usr_lastname, usr_jobtitle, usr_department, usr_email,
         team_name, team_streetno, team_city
```

The EXPLAIN output looks like this:

[image: explain image]

I tried this variation to make arrays out of the duplicated usr_id's and JOIN back to the usr table using `= ANY`; that *increased* the duration by about 15%.

```
 SELECT u.usr_id
     , t.team_name, t.team_streetno, t.team_city 
     , u.usr_firstname, u.usr_lastname, u.usr_jobtitle, u.usr_department, u.usr_email
  FROM (
      SELECT array_agg(u1.usr_id) dups
        FROM usr u1
        JOIN team t1 ON u1.team_id = t1.team_id
    GROUP BY match_firstname, match_lastname, match_jobtitle, match_department, match_email
           , match_team_name, match_team_streetno, match_team_city
      HAVING count(usr_id)>1
       ) AS dup
  JOIN usr u on u.usr_id = ANY (dup.dups)
  JOIN team t on t.team_id = u.team_id
ORDER BY u.usr_firstname, u.usr_lastname, u.usr_jobtitle, u.usr_department, u.usr_email
       , t.team_name, t.team_streetno, t.team_city
```

Look forward to your suggestions.

---

### Consolidating comments

Tried `WITH TMP AS (... ,count(*) over (partition by...) c FROM ..) WHERE c>1`, which fared worse than the arrag_agg/ANY approach. Seems like windowing functions in PostgreSQL is not that great, or it needs to be rewritten in another form.

For context, consider census data. If someone else filled it for you, he may fill in Tom one year, Thomas or Tomas the next. The "match" columns are derived from the base columns.

`EXISTS` has been tried, but didn't perform as well as the code shown above.

Comment: Using a derived table with `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` would be a test candidate.

Comment: And did you try the `EXISTS` way?

Comment: Also: I suppose you are talking about generic queries (no indexes on the several columns). Perhaps you should also be be comparing efficiency in regard with distribution (low or high percent of rows that match the `HAVING COUNT(*)>1` condition).

Comment: PKs of tables may be relevant to simplify `GROUP BY`, depending on your version of Postgres ...

Comment: @Erwin PKs are usr_id and team_id, does that help?

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: And which version of Postgres?

Comment: @Erwin 9.1.6. But is there really that much difference between that and 9.2 in relation to such a common query?

Comment: *Always* declare the version you are working with. Since you are dba-regular I am surprised I have to ask twice and even explain why. For instance, [`GROUP BY` can be simplified with the PK column since version 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-1.html#AEN113666).

Comment: Table definitions and some sample data would help a lot, too. Preferably as [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1)

Comment: @Erwin Apologies for stepping on your toes. The GROUP BY clause here does not *always* include all columns, only the ones on which to show duplicates, e.g. it could be just 3 columns from "usr" for example. SQLFiddle won't import 70k records... small tables don't tend to show anything useful. I asked this question thinking someone must have written similar queries, it isn't even fancy...

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: A test case is *almost always very useful*, even if we can't reproduce performance issues with it. I could test my queries, for one. Without it, I have to write blindfolded or whip up my own test case, which takes time and is error prone.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Updated after OP supplied test case voiding much of this answer.</sup>

#### Postgres version

There is a *good chance* Postgres 9.2 will perform better. A lot of improvements for big data have gone into it.

#### Simplified query

First off, you can simplify your query quite a bit:

```
SELECT u.usr_id
      ,t.team_name, t.team_streetno, t.team_city
      ,u.usr_firstname, u.usr_lastname, u.usr_jobtitle, u.usr_department, u.usr_email
FROM   usr  u
JOIN   team t USING (team_id)
JOIN (
   SELECT u.match_firstname, u.match_lastname, u.match_jobtitle, u.match_department
         ,u.match_email, t.match_team_name, t.match_team_streetno, t.match_team_city
   FROM   usr  u
   JOIN   team t USING (team_id)
   GROUP  BY u.match_firstname, u.match_lastname, u.match_jobtitle, u.match_department
            ,u.match_email, t.match_team_name, t.match_team_streetno, t.match_team_city
   HAVING count(usr_id) > 1
   ) AS sub USING (match_firstname, match_lastname, match_jobtitle, match_department
                  ,match_email, match_team_name, match_team_streetno, match_team_city)
ORDER  BY u.usr_firstname, u.usr_lastname, u.usr_jobtitle, u.usr_department, u.usr_email
         ,t.team_name, t.team_streetno, t.team_city;
```

- <strike>I removed the JOIN to the table `team` from the subquery, *guessing* that all the columns stem from table `usr` (my request for table definitions went unanswered ...) That should help a bit.</strike>
  Turns out, some of the columns belong to table team.
- I replace the verbose equijoin conditions with the much shorter `USING` syntax. That's also probably slightly faster.
- Replace `count(usr_id) > 1` with `count(*) > 1`. Does the same here (since `usr_id` is the PK, ergo `NOT NULL`), slightly faster.

I took the test case @RichardTheKiwi posted in the comments and created an [**sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1b79a/4) from it.

I also ran a local test with temporary tables on PostgreSQL 9.1.6.
Only slightly faster than the query in the question:
1338 ms for 15137 rows (out of 70k).

`EXISTS` semi-joins might be a hot contender if you have *many duplicates*. With only a few, not so much. You already tried and ruled that out. Are you positive you tried optimal syntax?

#### Window function `count()`

You could also *try* if `count()` as window function is faster - without CTE and without additional joins. But I doubt it. I sure does make the query shorter, though:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT u.usr_id
         ,t.team_name, t.team_streetno, t.team_city
         ,u.usr_firstname, u.usr_lastname, u.usr_jobtitle, u.usr_department, u.usr_email
         ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY
            u.match_firstname, u.match_lastname, u.match_jobtitle, u.match_department
           ,u.match_email, t.match_team_name, t.match_team_streetno, t.match_team_city) AS ct
   FROM  usr  u
   JOIN  team t USING (team_id)
   ) x
WHERE  ct > 1
ORDER  BY usr_firstname, usr_lastname, usr_jobtitle, usr_department
         ,usr_email, team_name, team_streetno, team_city;
```

50% slower in my local test.

#### Multi-column index?

<sup>This is largely obsolete after I have seen the test case.</sup>
Indexes are obviously hard to use here, since the columns to check for dupes vary. You *might* be able to profile user behavior and identify the most common combinations to support those with an index. There is a more radical possibility here, though:

Postgres can use multi-column indexes, even if not all index columns are used. Performance is *much* better if one or more leading columns of the index are used in the condition, but it still works if not. Compare:
[Working of indexes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql)

If we can assume that most use cases will check on, for instance,  `(match_firstname, match_lastname)`, a multi-column index like the following might help. Not sure, you'll have to test:

```
CREATE INDEX usr_match_multi_idx
ON usr (match_firstname, match_lastname, match_jobtitle, match_department, match_email);
```

Columns of the index in order of decreasing usefulness. Order of columns in your `GROUP BY` / `PARTITION BY` clause is not relevant.

Index did *not* help in my local test - was used, but made the query ~ 20 % slower.

#### Partial indexes?

**If** the table is *read-only* or at least *rarely written*
**and** many of your columns often have unique values, you could take this a step further. Rows with a *unique* value in one of the used match_* columns can be excluded right away. For columns with *many* unique values it would pay to either add a column `match_email_mult boolean` which you set `TRUE` if `match_email` is *not* unique for this row. Or, if you have many columns, you could use a `bit(n)` column or use an `integer` columns for an even small footprint on disk. More under [this related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051886/can-i-convert-a-bunch-of-boolean-columns-to-a-single-bitmask-in-postgresql).
Don't bother with columns with only few unique values.

```
CREATE INDEX usr_match_email_mult_idx ON usr (usr_id)
WHERE match_email_mult;
```

Repeat for all qualifying columns. Then add conditions to your query:

```
WHERE match_firstname_mult
AND   match_lastname_mult
AND   ...
```

Postgres can combine a number of bitmap index scans rather quickly. If that can weed out a *large portion* of the table to begin with, the query planner might switch from a sequential scan to bitmap-index scans ...

Not tested.

Comment: You're right, some sample data would help. So I've created a sample script that produces the distribution that I'm happy with here: http://pastebin.com/23grgHJp  Interestingly, the array_agg/ANY approach now finishes in 1 second, whereas the code in the question takes over a minute and still won't finish!

Comment: Took 2.5 minutes to complete, the EXPLAIN output shows it taking a scenic route

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: Your test case reveals a lot that's not in your question and voids much of my answer. I updated to refit it.