# Optimze performance for LIMIT / OFFEST on collected result of multiple queries

Tags: postgresql, optimization, performance, order-by, union, postgresql-performance

I have large tables in Postgres 10.4 (many millions rows) and three piped `SELECT` queries. The percentage of rows contributed to the total result for each `SELECT` is roughly:

- SELECT 1 : ~5 % rows
- SELECT 2 : ~5 % rows
- SELECT 3 : ~90 % rows

I can use `UNION` and `ORDER BY` and a `RANK` column, but it's very slow because Postgres collects rows from all subqueries and applies `ORDER BY RANK` on the result set.

Is there a way to have `SELECT 1` executed, and only if that does not provide enough rows `SELECT 2` is executed, etc.

Comment: Which PG version? Could you post your query? How many tables for those sub-query? You can simulate your structure in this https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: I use the postgresql 10.4. The type of request can will be 
```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT u.id,1 as rank FROM user u WHERE u.id = 3
    UNION
   SELECT u.id,2 as rank FROM user u WHERE troll = true
    UNION
   SELECT u.id,3 as rank FROM user u WHERE country_code = 'FR')
) as u
ORDER BY rank
OFFSET 0
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: I took the liberty to clarify your question. Please edit if I got anything wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general technique to achieve this, with `UNION ALL` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT 1 ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 ...
LIMIT N;
```

Postgres evaluates nested `SELECT`s in order and stops as soon as enough rows have been returned. The rest is ***never executed***.

This optimization does not happen with an outer `ORDER BY`, which forces Postgres to collect all candidate rows and sort *before* applying the `LIMIT`. Nor does it work for `UNION` (instead of `UNION ALL`) which also considers all rows before removing duplicates and, finally, the `LIMIT`.

You need parentheses around each nested `SELECT` that has `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` *in addition* to the outer `LIMIT`.

Related:

- [How to force order of WHERE clauses in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184287/how-to-force-order-of-where-clauses-in-postgresql/184309#184309)
- [Optimize a query on two big tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66294/optimize-a-query-on-two-big-tables/66338#66338)
- [How to give precedence to rows from one table over matching rows in another?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193660/how-to-give-precedence-to-rows-from-one-table-over-matching-rows-in-another/193914#193914)
- [Constraint exclusion to fetch latest N rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53437/constraint-exclusion-to-fetch-latest-n-rows/53451#53451)

Comment: That works perfectly :)