# Searching a big table for a few results without scanning the whole table

Tags: postgresql, performance, performance-tuning

I need to search a very big PostgreSQL table (500+M rows), I want to limit the returned search results, but using the "limit" keyword cant prevent the search over the whole set of data(is it correct?)

Imagine my search result contains 1M rows, but I need only the first 100 records in the search result! does PostgreSQL database have to create this 1M search result rows temporarily in memory and then give me my needed 100 results?

or is there any way to tell PostgreSQL to stop searching as soon as it find 100 records?

Here is my table, of course not populated with 500M records yet!

```
CREATE TABLE con
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  tag1 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  tag2 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  ref1 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  ref2 integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT con_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and the explain analyze for a test query:

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM con where tag1 = '64813' and tag2 = '80'
```

```
Seq Scan on con  (cost=0.00..3215204.72 rows=2470 width=112) (actual time=0.016..36970.528 rows=7505 loops=1)
   Filter: ((tag1 = 64813) AND (tag2 = 80))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 152519685
Total runtime: 36972.921 ms
```

Comment: If you have the right index add a where condition so that will return 100 rows,using a seek.I think with limit it needs to get the whole data.

Comment: It depends. :-) The optimizer will do its best to avoid unneeded work but if it has to sort 1M rows first and then return you the first 100 of those, there might be no way to avoid that -- unless you can create an index for that sort order. But that's not always possible if, eg joins are needed to create the result set.

Comment: As it is, this question runs the risk of being closed as being "unclear". Please add your SQL, table definitions (including indexes and constraints) and the output of `explain analyze`.

Comment: thank you for the comments, at the time if I don't need the result sorted, is there any chance I can escape from loading that 1M records? does proper indexing help in this case?

Comment: Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I have updated the question as you said :)

Answer (score 5):

> but using the "limit" keyword cant prevent the search over the whole set of data(is it correct?)

Correct; it'll just limit how many results are returned.

For *some kinds of query* it can also limit how many are scanned in the first place, but you can't rely on that in the general case.

> does PostgreSQL database have to create this 1M search result rows temporarily in memory and then give me my needed 100 results?

Create, yes. In memory, not necessarily. It'll often spill to disk, or discard unneeded results as it goes so it only keeps the top 100. It depends on the details of the query.

> or is there any way to tell PostgreSQL to stop searching as soon as it find 100 records?

Write a query where that is possible. You haven't shown the query, or schema, so this part is impossible to usefully answer.

In general, if you have an `ORDER BY` on some kind of search relevance field then the whole data set must be searched then filtered for the top-n results.

In short: "It depends". Specifically, it depends on the schema, available indexes, and on *exactly* what you're searching for and what results you want.

This:

```
SELECT id 
FROM mytable 
WHERE somefield > 100 
ORDER BY somefield DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

would only scan the needed rows if there was an index on `mytable(somefield DESC)`.

This:

```
SELECT id, title
FROM mytable
WHERE title LIKE '%something%'
ORDER BY calculate_relevance(title, 'something')
LIMIT 100;
```

would always scan the whole table, both because an infix text pattern match (`LIKE '%blah%'`) can't use a b-tree index, and because you can't create an expression index on a function taking a literal parameter like the case of the imaginary `calculate_relevance` function above.

So... it depends totally on what you're searching for and how.

---

*Is this answer too hand-wavey and general for you? So's the question. Supply specifics, and you'll get more specific answers. A http://sqlfiddle.com/ of the schema with sample data, plus your PostgreSQL version, a table of the expected results, and a description of what you want to find is usually the minimum for this kind of thing.*

---

**Update**: A few problems here.

- There's no index on `tag1` and/or `tag2` so Pg must do a seqscan of the table, searching it until it finds 100 results. This is extremely inefficient.
- There's no `ORDER BY`, so PostgreSQL can return whatever results it feels like for a `LIMIT` and return them in any order.
- Your schema shows signs of being unnecessarily denormalized. `tag1`, `tag2`, etc usually suggest bad table design. I strongly recommend that you study relational database design and [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

In this specific case, you'd be able to avoid the full table scan if you `CREATE INDEX con_tag1_tag2_idx ON con(tag1, tag2)`. But that'll only work for searches that use `tag1` and optionally also `tag2`. [It won't help (much) with searches for just `tag2`, searches for `ref1`, etc](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql/7484#7484). (Thanks Erwin for the important note on multicolumn index use with the first column not included, it was a surprise to me).

Don't create lots of indexes. Each one uses disk space and takes disk I/O to insert, update and delete.

The answer is often proper normalization.

Overall I think you need to buy/borrow a couple of good introductory books on relational database design and basic to intermediate SQL, preferably PostgreSQL-focused, and do some study.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, I tried to add some details on my table and query (sorry for the bad formatting of my sql, I don't know how to make it look better in here). currently I don't care about the order of results, or the order the records was inserted is good for me, is there any suggestion in this condition? I'm afraid for the cases that the search criteria is so generic, so that a search query return several millions of records wasting cpu power and overuse the memory!

Comment: @chakoshi The help (linked to when you're editing an answer) tells you how to format. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . There's also a toolbar with buttons that have tooltips to tell you what to click to format! The `{}` button on the toolbar was all you needed. You have also not really defined what you want.

Comment: @chakoshi Anyway, see edit. Overall I really think you need to go back to basics here.

Comment: thanks for the edit! I'm no  expert on db but I know the basics on normalization, the reason I left those 4 tag1,tag2,ref1,ref2 fields in the table was that they all going to hold any 4byte integers with specific meanings for each row, I guessed it wouldn't help if I replace them with a key to another table (those integers could be highly variable and maybe unique in the whole table). is there still any benefit to normalize them? btw, I'll work on the indexing stuff you suggested.

Comment: `It won't help with searches for just tag2`. Well, half true: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql/7484#7484

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter That is enlightening and astonishing. It's contrary to the documentation and something I was completely unaware of. Pg must be scanning every leaf of the first column to reach the subtrees for the second column. I wonder when that was introduced?

Comment: @CraigRinger: It was introduced with Postgres 8.1, but I am not sure about how it's implemented exactly. Where would say the documentation is contradicting? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql/6426#6426

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Re-checking, nowhere apparently. *A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with query conditions that involve any subset of the index's columns, but the index is most efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost) columns.* http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-multicolumn.html