# Take advantage of monotonic columns in PostreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

I have a PostgreSQL table with, among the other, two columns named `col1` and `col2`, both of integer type (there are around 10M rows in the table). I want to perform SQL queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 >= val1 AND col2 <= val2;
```

(for certain `val1` and `val2` that I know a query time).

If I put btree indices on `col1` and `col2` PostgreSQL tries to execute the query performing an index scan on one of the two columns and then filtering on the other. This means that in most cases it has to sweep through around half of the table, even when the number of matching rows is very little. Adding a multicolumn index is useless, because PostgreSQL can effectively use it only when at least one of the two columns is tested for equality.

One important assumption that I can make on the values, though, is that the two columns are monotonic one respect to the other. This means that if in a row `col1` is greater then or equal two `col1` in another row, then the same relation is valid between the two corresponding `col2` entries.

This means that in line of principle the query execution could be sped up by performing an index scan on one of the two columns, filtering on the other and stopping the execution as soon as a non matching value is found on the second column. In this case the query would read just exactly the rows to be returned.

Is there any way to setup indices or whatever other invariant in PostgreSQL so that the query planner is able to detect this?

(of course the problem can be easily solved performing two queries, the first one to translate the inequality on `col2` to an inequality on `col1`; I am asking if there is a way to avoid this workaround and let PostgreSQL manage the mess by itself)

Comment: "*Adding a multicolumn index is useless*" - are you sure? Did you test it?

Comment: hmmm, I should probably read the *whole* question before answering. Why would you want to avoid the workaround? The issue here is that you know your data better than postgres knows it (how could pg be sure the two columns are going to be monotonically related *tomorrow* even if it can see that they are today?)

Comment: Also, you may like to read all the answers [on this related question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6115/1396)

Comment: @JackDouglas I have no real reasons to avoid the workaround, and that is actually what I am implementing. I just wanted to potentially learn something on databases that I do not know.

Answer (score 3):

> if in a row col1 is greater then or equal two col1 in another row, then the same relation is valid between the two corresponding col2 entries

In which case you can reformulate your query to look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col2 >= val1 AND col2 <= val2;
```

because you can find the lower bound for `col2` from the lower bound for `col1`, like this:

schema:

```
create schema stack;
set search_path=stack;
--
create table t(foo integer, bar integer);
insert into t(foo,bar) select 10*g, 20*g from generate_series(1,100000) g;
create index on t(foo);
create index on t(bar);
```

method:

> ```
> explain analyse select min(foo) from t where foo>500; -- assuming val1=500
> ```
>
> ```
> ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                               │
> ├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ Result  (cost=0.38..0.39 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.063..0.064 rows=1 loops=1)                                                    │
> │   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)                                                                                                             │
> │     ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..0.38 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.059..0.060 rows=1 loops=1)                                             │
> │           ->  Index Only Scan using t_foo_idx on t  (cost=0.29..2803.63 rows=33167 width=4) (actual time=0.058..0.058 rows=1 loops=1) │
> │                 Index Cond: ((foo IS NOT NULL) AND (foo > 500))                                                                       │
> │                 Heap Fetches: 1                                                                                                       │
> │ Total runtime: 0.087 ms                                                                                                               │
> └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
> ```
>
> ```sql
> select min(foo) from t where foo>500;
> ```
>
> ```
> ┌─────┐
> │ min │
> ├─────┤
> │ 510 │
> └─────┘
> ```
>
> ```sql
> select min(bar) from t where foo=510;
> ```
>
> ```
> ┌──────┐
> │ min  │
> ├──────┤
> │ 1020 │
> └──────┘
> ```
>
> ```sql
> explain analyse select * from t where bar>=1020 and bar<= 1100; -- assuming val2=1100
> ```
>
> ```
> ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                      │
> ├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ Bitmap Heap Scan on t  (cost=13.42..485.00 rows=500 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.013 rows=5 loops=1)              │
> │   Recheck Cond: ((bar >= 1020) AND (bar <= 1100))                                                                   │
> │   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t_bar_idx  (cost=0.00..13.29 rows=500 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=5 loops=1) │
> │         Index Cond: ((bar >= 1020) AND (bar <= 1100))                                                               │
> │ Total runtime: 0.030 ms                                                                                             │
> └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
> ```
>
> ```sql
> select * from t where bar>=1020 and bar<= 1100;
> ```
>
> ```
> ┌─────┬──────┐
> │ foo │ bar  │
> ├─────┼──────┤
> │ 510 │ 1020 │
> │ 520 │ 1040 │
> │ 530 │ 1060 │
> │ 540 │ 1080 │
> │ 550 │ 1100 │
> └─────┴──────┘
> ```

clean up:

```
drop schema stack cascade;
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this can be done (and I already suggested that in the last parenthetical in my question). My question was really about the possibility to describe constraints that instructed PostgreSQL to do that by itself (and at this point the answer is probably "No, it cannot be done"). Thanks for the detailed answer anyway.

Comment: I noticed that [too late](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90069/take-advantage-of-monotonic-columns-in-postresql/90070#comment161621_90069) :)

Comment: Oh, I had not noticed the time progression of the things.

Comment: you might be interested to know that ypercube suggested [a simpler version](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19703132#19703132) of this answer in The Heap

Comment: @giomasce: using Jack's sample setup (but adding additional columns to make it more realistic), Postgres uses a combined index on both columns, so I'm wondering why you think it wouldn't help: http://explain.depesz.com/s/ogtw

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name does the plan show what percentage of the index is touched, or if not is there any way of getting that statistic?

Comment: The `Buffers: read = 275` indicates this (275 blocks were read) and the index is indeed 275 blocks in size. But that was the query `where bar >= 1020 and bar <= 1100` when I use `bar >= 1020 and foo <= 1100` (the original query) Postgres visits only parts of the index: http://explain.depesz.com/s/PEwA (the second plan was taken with 5 million rows in the sample table)

Comment: Here is a complete fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d48e/1 You can see that the index scan only retrieved 3 blocks (`Buffers: shared hit=3`) which accounts for roughly 1000 rows that were evaluated to get the result out of 100.000

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks. Those 3 blocks touched are [all the rows with `foo<=1100`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d48e/2). If that `foo` condition doesn't restrict the matched rows much [then most of the index is scanned](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d48e/11) even when the query ultimately returns the same number of rows (113).

Comment: This might be a bit more realistic: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dfcd4/6. And still it is just 1M rows, I have 10M. As explained by @JackDouglas, a double index still requires to scan most of it in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ranges? Maythe the indexing methods for them (gist) can give you desired performance (for large datasets). Though gist indexes come with some tradeoffs (size, build-time, index-time for simple queries).

Some testing code:

```
create table t(id serial primary key, some_col text, foo numrange);

insert into t(some_col, foo) 
select 'foobar', numrange(10*g, 20*g, '[]') from generate_series(1,50000) g;

create index ix_foo_bar on t  using gist (foo) ;
analyze t;
```

And querying it:

```
explain (analyze, buffers, verbose)
select * 
from t 
where foo @> numrange(1020, 1100, '[]');
```

Comment: In my case ranges are not a viable alternative. I simplified the question supposing that the two columns are of integer type, but they are actually one integer type (the table primary key) and one floating-point type. I think this means that your suggestion cannot be implemented. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @giomasce it doesn't necessarily mean that - a functional index could cast/round. eg if your fp values are between 0 and 1, and your integers between 0 and 1000, multiply by 1000 and round for the index. Obviously your query will have to do the same conversion as the index for it to be used.