# Why is a GiST index used for filtering on non-leading column?

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning, postgresql-12, gist-index

I always learned and understood that an index can only be used when we have predicates for the leading (or all) columns. Now, to my surprise, I noticed that a [GiST index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist.html) is used in the following query. Why is that? Is this a special feature of GiST indexes?

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    i INT, 
    j INT, 
    k INT
);

INSERT INTO t1 
SELECT i, j, k 
FROM   GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100) AS i, 
       GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100) AS j, 
       GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100) AS k;

CREATE INDEX ON t1 USING GiST(i, j, k);

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE k = 54;
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Bitmap Heap Scan on t1  (cost=199.03..5780.51 rows=5000 width=12)
  Recheck Cond: (k = 54)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on t1_i_j_k_idx  (cost=0.00..197.78 rows=5000 width=0)
        Index Cond: (k = 54)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e40988cd9745f7cd2949e844ceb294f0)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> an index can only be used when we have predicates for the leading (or all) columns.

In Postgres, this rule of thumb is only somewhat applicable to (default) **B-tree** indexes. See:

- [Working of indexes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql)

But mostly wrong for **GiST** indexes. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html)

> A multicolumn GiST index can be used with query conditions that
> involve **any subset of the index's columns**. Conditions on additional
> columns restrict the entries returned by the index, but the condition
> on the first column is the most important one for determining how much
> of the index needs to be scanned. A GiST index will be relatively
> ineffective if its first column has only a few distinct values, even
> if there are many distinct values in additional columns.

So, generally, you put columns (or expressions) with the most distinct values first in a GiST index.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL exclusion constraints in a bitemporal setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62765428/939860)

It's different for other index types. For (also very common) [**GIN** indexes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html)

> A multicolumn GIN index can be used with query conditions that involve
> any subset of the index's columns. Unlike B-tree or GiST, index search
> effectiveness is the same regardless of which index column(s) the
> query conditions use.

The whole chapter of the manual is recommended reading.